# What does this Javascript code mean?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “options = options || {}” mean in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851404/what-does-options-options-mean-in-javascript)

Looking at the YouTube source...

```
var yt = yt || {};
```

Does that mean.. set `yt` to `yt` if `yt` exists, else create a new object?

If that's the case, I didn't think you can put a condition when declaring a variable.

Comment: See [What does "options = options || {}" mean in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851404/what-does-options-options-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the value of `yt` back to `yt` unless it is any of `0`, `NaN`, `false`, `null`, `""`, or `undefined` (i.e. it's *falsy*), in which case assign `{}` to `yt`.

This works because each of the values in the list above evaluate to `false` in a boolean expression.

Comment: You forgot the empty string: `Boolean('') === false`

Answer (score 3):

It means exactly that: If the content does not evaluate to false, assign it to itself (which is a neutral operation), otherwise create a new object and assign it to `yt`. It's typically used to instantiate objects to use as namespaces, first checking if the namespace already exists.

Comment: Not exactly. Consider: `var yt = NaN;
yt = yt || {};` In this case `yt` *exists*, but the final result will be `{}`.

Comment: @lwburk : yes, but it's not an object.

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. The empty string is an object and will produce the same result.

Comment: Hrm, perhaps I should revise. It's true that `"" instanceof  Object` evaluates to `false`. I still think your wording is incorrect. If `yt` is the empty string or `0` (or whatever), then clearly it *exists*.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate `yt`, if it evaluates falsey, then instantiate it as an object.

The first time I saw somthing like this was :

```
function handleEvent(e){
    e=e||window.event;
}
```

pretty nifty~ anyone know of other languages that support this syntax? (Not PHP =(

Comment: Why would `yt` be false? It doesn't look like a boolean var. Or do you mean false as in the object doesn't yet exist ?

Comment: @marko false==undefined==null==0 in conditions in javascript

Comment: It's not whether `yt` is false, it's whether it's falsy.  There are several things besides false that are [falsy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535647/logical-operators-in-javascript-how-do-you-use-them/4535656#4535656), including (as Marko alluded to), `undefined`.

Comment: It's a matter of what is falsey~  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982663/falsey-values-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks @Matthew, I hadn't heard of `falsy` before.

Comment: Php actually does support this (assignment with an `||` or `or`), it just doesn't do what you think it would a whole lot of the time, so it's pretty useless other than for some error handling (`$result = mysql_query($query) or die(print_err(mysql_error())`).

Comment: @jeremiahd I use that syntax a lot but I had never thought of the parallel. =) (I wish it worked with assignment)

Comment: @Shad well it doesn't throw a syntax error. It does, however, mostly return the value the boolean operator returned instead of the value the lhs or rhs evaluated to. I'm pretty sure I've seen it act that way before, but I know that if it does, it's spotty :( . You can at least achieve the same thing with a ternary: `$yt = $yt ? $yt : Array();`

Comment: @jeremiahd Yeah, ternary assignment is fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the whole right side of the expression is evaluated first before the assignment. So if `yt==false` the value of the expression on the RHS will be `{}` and get passed to the `var yt`

Comment: No, it's not whether it's equal to false, it's whether it's falsy.