# JavaScript if statement always returns true

Tags: javascript, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

corresponding html:

```
<html>
<title></title>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<FORM NAME="Calculator">
<TABLE BORDER=4>
<TR>
<TD>
<input type="text"   name="Input" Size="22" value="">
<input type="text" name="notepad" value="">
<br>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="one"   VALUE="  1  " class ="digit" >
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="two"   VALUE="  2  " class ="digit" >
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="three" VALUE="  3  " class ="digit" >
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="plus"  VALUE="  +  " class ="operand">
<br>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="four"  VALUE="  4  " class ="digit">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="five"  VALUE="  5  " class ="digit">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="six"   VALUE="  6  " class ="digit">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="minus" VALUE="  -  " class="operand">
<br>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="seven" VALUE="  7  " class ="digit">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="eight" VALUE="  8  " class ="digit">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="nine"  VALUE="  9  " class ="digit">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="times" VALUE="  x  " class ="operand">
<br>
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="clear" VALUE="  c  " class ="special">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="zero"  VALUE="  0  " class ="digit">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="Execute"  VALUE="  = " class ="solve">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="div"   VALUE="  /  " class ="operand">
<br>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</FORM>

<script type = "text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Quonn\Desktop\QBJS\calculatorjs.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
document.onclick = function(x) {
  var info = x.target;
  if (info.className === "digit" || "operand")
  {
    addDigit();
  }
  else {
    math();
  }
}

function addDigit() {
  alert("x");
}

function math() {
  alert("y");
}
```

x is passed in from button clicks on a calculator. The if statement returns as true even when info.className is something other than digit/operand.
What do i need to change in my if statement to make it return false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (info.className === "digit" || info.className === "operand")
```

Answer (score 4):

You're not using the `||` operator correctly.

The `||` operator is used to ***OR*** two values.  It appears *between* the two values.

From your example:

**FIRST** it checks the left side of your condition:

`info.className === "digit"`

If *true*, the `||` operator returns *true* (it doesn't evaluate the right side).

Otherwise it evaluates the right side of your condition:

`"operand"`

This will **ALWAYS** evaluate to *true*, because the string "operand" does **NOT** equal a *[falsey value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3982663/778118)*.

To fix this, you need to use the correct expression on both sides of the `||` operator:

```
if (info.className === "digit" || info.className === "operand") {
    alert("Yay");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a string interpreted as a boolean will always return true.

if (info.className === "digit" || "operand")
should be
if (info.className == "digit" || info.className == "operand")