# Is empty string treated as falsy in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've noticed that if you have a statement as the following:

```
var test = "" || null
```

`test` will evaluate to `null` but if we do something like the following:

```
var test = "test" || null
```

`test` will evaluate to "test", the same holds true for any object in place of the string, so does javascript treat empty string as either a falsy or null value, and if so why? Isn't an empty string still an object, so shouldn't it be handled the same?

I've tested this out in FireFox, Chrome, IE7/8/9, and Node.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Does javascript treat empty string as either a falsy or null value, and if so why?

Yes it does, and because [the spec says so (§9.2)](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2).

> Isn't an empty string still an object

No. An primitive string value is no object, only a `new String("")` would be (and would be truthy)

Comment: Ah makes more sense now, thanks! It still seems like an odd decision to me to make empty string falsy, but I guess I have to get used to thinking of strings as a primitive type, instead of objects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes an empty string is falsy, however `new String("")` is not.

Note also that it's well possible that

```
if (x) { ... }
```

is verified, but that

```
if (x == false) { ... }
```

is verified too (this happens for example with an empty array `[]` or with `new String("")`).

Answer (score 0):

String is not an object, it's a primitive like number or boolean.

The empty string, NaN, +0, -0, false, undefined and null are the only values which evaluate to false in direct boolean conversion.

Answer (score 0):

A string isn't an object in JS. Other "falsy" values are: `0`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

One dangerous issue of falsey values you have to be aware of is when checking the presence of a certain property.

Suppose you want to test for the availability of a new property; when this property can actually have a value of 0 or "", you can't simply check for its availability using

```
 if (!someObject.someProperty)
    /* incorrectly assume that someProperty is unavailable */
In this case, you must check for it being really present or not:

if (typeof someObject.someProperty == "undefined")
    /* now it's really not available */
```

[**SEE HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982663/falsey-values-in-javascript)