# All falsey values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

**What are the values in JavaScript that are 'falsey'**, meaning that they evaluate as false in expressions like `if(value)`, `value ?` and `!value`?

---

There are [some discussions of the purpose of falsey values on Stack Overflow already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982663/falsey-values-in-javascript), but no exhaustive complete answer listing what all the falsey values are.

[I couldn't find any complete list on MDN JavaScript Reference](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&as_q=falsy%20OR%20falsey&as_sitesearch=developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript), and I was surprised to find that the top results when looking for a complete, authoritative list of falsey values in JavaScript were blog articles, some of which had obvious omissions (for example, `NaN`), and none of which had a format like Stack Overflow's where comments or alternative answers could be added to point out quirks, surprises, omissions, mistakes or caveats. So, it seemed to make sense to make one.

Comment: [Did you check the language spec?](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/)

Comment: @tibos http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/ is a great resource and has an `if()` tab for truthiness.

Comment: Wow, really useful, thanks! `[[]] == ""` but `[] != []`?My head hurts...

Comment: The ECMA 262 Specification details these comparison rules, specifically sec 11.9.1 through 11.9.6: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

It would be swell if you updated your answer to include this reference, since it provides the rules for how true/false determinations are (supposed to be) made.

Comment: Likewise, the ECMA-262 specification for "ToBoolean" behavior is well documented: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2

Comment: At least nowadays, there's some information on MDN in a different part of the web site than what you searched: (in docs/Glossary/Falsy rather than docs/Web/JavaScript) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Answer (score 453, accepted):

### Falsey values in JavaScript

- `false`
- Zero of `Number` type: `0` and also [`-0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223717/differentiating-0-and-0), `0.0`, and hex form `0x0` ([thanks RBT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46311408/568458))
- Zero of [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) type: `0n` and `0x0n` (new in 2020, [thanks GetMeARemoteJob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61551634/568458))
- `""`, `''` and [``` `` ```](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) - strings of length 0
- `null`
- `undefined`
- `NaN`
- `document.all` (in HTML browsers only)

  - This is a weird one. `document.all` is a falsey object, with `typeof` as `undefined`. It was a Microsoft-proprietory function in IE before IE11, and was added to the [HTML spec as a "willful violation of the JavaScript specification"](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/obsolete.html#dom-document-all) so that sites written for IE wouldn't break on trying to access, for example, `document.all.something`; it's falsy because `if (document.all)` used to be a popular way to detect IE, before conditional comments. See [Why is document.all falsy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10350142/1048572) for details

**"Falsey" simply means that JavaScript's internal [`ToBoolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_reference/JS::ToBoolean) function returns `false`.** `ToBoolean` underlies `!value`, `value ? ... : ...;` and `if (value)`. Here's its [**official specification (2020 working draft)**](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-toboolean) (the only changes since the [very first ECMAscript specification in 1997](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%201st%20edition,%20June%201997.pdf) are the addition of [ES6's Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol), which are always truthy, and `BigInt`, mentioned above:

> | Argument type | Result |
> | --- | --- |
> | Undefined | Return `false`. |
> | Null | Return `false`. |
> | Boolean | Return *argument*. |
> | Number | If argument is `+0`, `-0`, or `NaN`, return `false`; otherwise return `true`. |
> | String | If argument is the empty `String` (its length is zero), return `false`; otherwise return `true`. |
> | BigInt | If argument is `0n`, return `false`; otherwise return `true`. |
> | Symbol | Return `true`. |
> | Object | Return `true`. |

---

### Comparisons with `==` (loose equality)

It's worth talking about falsy values' [loose comparisons with `==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness), which uses [`ToNumber()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_reference/JS::ToNumber) and can cause some confusion due to the underlying differences. They effectively form three groups:

- **`false, 0, -0, "", ''`** all match each other with `==`

  - e.g. `false == ""`, `'' == 0` and therefore `4/2 - 2 == 'some string'.slice(11);`
- **`null, undefined`** match with `==`

  - e.g. `null == undefined` but `undefined != false`
  - It's also worth mentioning that while `typeof null` returns `'object'`, `null` is [not an object, this is a longstanding bug/quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808226/why-is-typeof-null-object) that was not fixed in order to maintain compatibility. It's not a true object, and objects are truthy (except for that "wilful violation" `document.all` when Javascript is implemented in HTML)
- **`NaN`** [doesn't match anything, with `==` or `===`, not even itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

  - e.g. `NaN != NaN`, `NaN !== NaN`, `NaN != false`, `NaN != null`

With "strict equality" (`===`), there are no such groupings. Only `false` `===` `false`.

This is one of the reasons why many developers and many style guides (e.g. [standardjs](https://standardjs.com/)) prefer `===` and almost never use `==`.

---

### Truthy values that actually `== false`

"Truthy" simply means that JavaScript's internal [`ToBoolean`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_reference/JS::ToBoolean) function returns `true`. **A quirk of Javascript to be aware of** (and another good reason to prefer `===` over `==`): it is possible for a value to be truthy (`ToBoolean` returns `true`), but also `== false`.

You might think `if (value && value == false) alert('Huh?')` is a logical impossibility that couldn't happen, but it will, for:

- `"0"` and `'0'` - they're non-empty strings, which are truthy, but Javascript's `==` matches numbers with equivalent strings (e.g. `42 == "42"`). Since `0 == false`, if  `"0" == 0`, `"0" == false`.
- `new Number(0)` and `new Boolean(false)` - they're objects, which are truthy, but `==` sees their values, which `== false`.
- `0 .toExponential();` - an object with a numerical value equivalent to `0`
- Any similar constructions that give you a false-equaling value wrapped in a type that is truthy
- `[]`, `[[]]` and `[0]` (thanks [cloudfeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472388/cloudfeet) for the [JavaScript Equality Table link](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/))

---

### Some more truthy values

These are just a few values that some people might expect to be falsey, but are actually truthy.

- `-1` and all non-zero negative numbers
- `' '`, `" "`, `"false"`, `'null'`... *all* non-empty strings, including strings that are just whitespace
- Anything from `typeof`, which always returns a non-empty string, for example:

  - `typeof null` (returns a string `'object'` [due to a longstanding bug/quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808226/why-is-typeof-null-object))
  - `typeof undefined` (returns a string `'undefined'`)
- Any object (except that "wilful violation" `document.all` in browsers). Remember that `null` isn't really an object, despite `typeof` suggesting otherwise. Examples:

  - `{}`
  - `[]`
  - `function(){}` or [`() => {}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (any function, including empty functions)
  - `Error` and any instance of `Error`
  - Any regular expression
  - Anything created with `new` (including `new Number(0)` and `new Boolean(false)`)
- Any [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)

`true`, `1`, `"1"` and `[1]` return `true` when compared to each other with `==`.

Comment: FYI, what `!`, `if` and `?..:` have in common is that they call the internal `ToBoolean` function on the value. How those values behave in the context of `!`, `if`, etc. is already implied by their name: They are "falsy" values. I'm a bit afraid that others will read the answer and think *"Oh so in this context (`!`, `if`, `?...:`), the value is `false`, but with `!!`, it's `true`"*, but don't understand the underlying concept. Two other points: 1) `v ? true : false` is just a verbose way of `!!v`. 2) `typeof` *always* returns a non-empty string,  which is truthy.

Comment: I.e. there is no point in looking at `typeof null` or `typeof undefined` specifically. You could just say that non-empty strings are truthy.

Comment: I see, but this has nothing to do with the original question ;) Adding too much somewhat related but not relevant information could be rather confusing for readers.

Comment: I have just learned that [`document.all` is falsy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35642837/15055) as well.

Comment: Regarding  loose comparison: because Booleans are converted to numbers, `x == false` will call `ToNumber(x)` which is just very different from `ToBoolean(x)`. Might be worth explaining. Also I just noticed that I already commented on this answer ages ago :D

Comment: Is there a reason to consider `''` and `""` to be separate values?

Comment: `""` and `''` are alternative notations for the same value. They should be in the same bullet. And if you're going to do that, you may as well include `void 0` next to `undefined`.

Comment: It's questionable whether `document.all` should be included in this list. This question is about JavaScript, not HTML.

Comment: @Hans that's why I say "This is a weird one" and that it was "added to the HTML spec as a 'willful violation of the JavaScript specification'"...

Comment: Why are `0x0` and `0x0n` specially mentioned, but not `0b0` or `0o0` or `0e0`, etc.?

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to @user568458's list of falsy values:

- In addition to integer number 0, the decimal number 0.0, 0.00 or any such zeroish number is also a falsy value.

  ```
  var myNum = 0.0;
  if(myNum){
      console.log('I am a truthy value');
  }
  else {
      console.log('I am a falsy value');
  }
  ```

  Above code snippet prints `I am a falsy value`
- Similarly hex representation of the number 0 is also a falsy value as shown in below code snippet:

  ```
  var myNum = 0x0; //hex representation of 0
  if(myNum){
      console.log('I am a truthy value');
  }   
  else {
      console.log('I am a falsy value');
  }
  ```

  Above code snippet again prints `I am a falsy value`.

Comment: JavaScript does not have integer numbers. `0`, `0x0`, `0.0` and `0.00` are just different literals for the same IEEE-754 64-bit floating point value zero.

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget about the non-empty string `"false"` which evaluates to `true`

Comment: …and is therefore not a falsy value, which was asked for?

Comment: touché. it's a value you might expect to be falsey and isn't, which is still worth being aware of, and I think, merits mention on a comprehensive list

Comment: Added to the list... but let's not try to turn this into a comprehensive list of all possible truthy values! That'd take a while `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

Addition to the topic, as of ES2020 we have a new value which is falsy, it's BigInt zero (0n):

```
0n == false // true
-0n == false // true
0n === false // false
-0n === false // false
```

So with this, we now have 7 "falsy" values in total (not including document.all as mentioned by user above since it's part of DOM and not JS).

Comment: Nice! Thanks, I hadn't heard about that yet, I've added it to the big list with a link crediting your answer for raising it