# What does "|| 0" do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of JavaScript code that shows:

```
function(next, feather) {
  var l = Number(171) + (next || 0);
  var m = Math.max(1, l - 9);
  return {
    lc: 300 * (l + 1) * m + (5 * feather || 0)
  }
}
```

Now I've simplified it a little bit. But can anyone explain what the "|| 0" does? As far as I can tell it does nothing.

(Notice I replaced a function with Number(171), as that function effectively returns a number, feather is also supposed to be a number, 0 most of the time, 1 sometimes).

Comment: It does `OR 0`, so if whatever is on the left side is falsy, it inserts a `0` instead.

Comment: and many of [`[javascript] "||"`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%22%7C%7C%22).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well if you *know* `next` and `feather` are numbers, then yes, it has no function. However, if you were to pass in a value like `undefined`, which is effectively what will happen if you call the function without specifying any parameters, you'll see some difference:

```
var next = undefined;
console.log(171 + next);        // NaN
console.log(171 + (next || 0)); // 171
```

Of course, this isn't a foolproof method. Passing in `null` has no effect on the computation, and passing a non-empty string (e.g. `"1"`), will result in something *very* different.

Comment: Aah, i get it, this function is offten called with no parameters. Does the 0 get used in that case?

Answer (score 7):

If `next` is [falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript-values-where-value-is-true), `0` will be used in its place. JavaScript has no default value operator, so users have leveraged this approach, even though the language's creator has [called it an *abusage*](https://brendaneich.com/2012/04/the-infernal-semicolon/).

[image: Animated illustration of answer]

Comment: Correct.  For example, if feather is a string, 5 * feather = NaN.  || 0 prevents this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`variable || 0` looks up the variable, and if it is undefined, null, or empty (i.e. zero), it will use the number 0 instead. This actually makes sense because if it was anything other than zero itself, it would return `NaN`.

If that didn't make any sense, this should:

```
undefined * 1 == NaN;
(undefined || 0) * 1 == 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` and `||` operators in JavaScript will shortcut evaluation. The way it's set up in the example you gave, if 'next' evaluates to a boolean TRUE then that will be added to 'l', otherwise '0' will be added.

Answer (score 1):

If the `next` is [falsy](http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/10/17/true-lies-and-falsy-values-in-python-and-javascript/) (false-like value) zero is used instead.

E.g.
        next || 0

equals something like

```
    if(!next) { return 0 } else { return next; }
```

It forces false-like values to be an actual zero number.

Answer (score 1):

If the context before the **logical or** `||` is falsy (this includes nulls and undefineds), then it will take the value after it. So in your case, if `next` or `feather` is not defined or 0, then the value of 0 will be used in those calculations within the parenthesis, essentially the code will read as the following if both are 0 or *undefined*:

```
function(next, feather) {
  var l = Number(171) + 0;
  var m = Math.max(1, l - 9);
  return {
    lc: 300 * (l + 1) * m + 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the OR operator `||` in this scenario is basically short hand for checking weather or not `next` was included. If it were coming from some sort of number calculation, perhaps it was possible that next was `NaN` at times (which is always falsy) and so this was the workaround to make it 0.

```
var l = Number(171) + (next || 0);
```

A more readable approach would be to test for that case at the inset of the function

```
if( isNaN(next) )next = 0;
```

Or to also include other tests as well

```
if( isNaN(next) || next === null || typeof(next) === "undefined" )next = 0;
```