# JavaScript operator precedence and associativity

Tags: javascript, operators

In JavaScript

```
var x = (5 >= 9 >= 0);
console.log(x);
// returns true
```

What is happening in that statement and what is the reason for that output?

Comment: This will create syntax error. Did you mean `var` instead of `boolean`?

Comment: What do you think happens?

Comment: What did you expect instead of `true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `true` statement, is understood as *different from zero*... Consequently, `false` is *equals zero*...

The statement:

```
(5>=9>=0)
```

Turns into

```
(false >= 0)
```

Since 5 is lower than 9. Then, if false is equal zero the result is *true*

**EDIT**

As explained here ([All falsey values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript-values-where-value-is-true)), zero is among the falsy values in javascript...

Answer (score 3):

The [Operator precedence and Associativity chart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) explains what is happening. The expression is evaluated in this order:

```
/* 1 */ x = (5 >= 9) >= 0;
/* 2 */ x = false >= 0;
/* 3 */ x = true;
```

Explanation:

1. `>=` is left associative the operator between 5 and 9 is evaluated first.
2. `>=` uses abstract comparison which converts boolean to number i.e. `false` becomes 0 ([ref](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.4)).
3. The end result is `true`.

Comment: (5>=9) = true? really?

Comment: LOL (false >= 0) = false?

Comment: The real question is, why is `false == 0` in non-strict comparison

Comment: @adeneo—you're kidding? Because [*ToNumber(false)*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) is zero.

Comment: @RobG - I'm not kidding, it's probably not very clear to everyone why `false >= 0` returns `true` as it's clearly not the same thing, or false being "more" than zero, it's because of the forced coercion to numbers on both sides, which is interesting.

Comment: @adeneo unfortunately there is no `>==` operator :)

Comment: @adeneo—the greater–than and less–that operators use the [*abstract relation algorithm*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5), so there's a not–so–subtle hint that the comparison isn't strict. Maybe there's room for a strict relational comparison? ;-)