# Shouldn't "return doc && doc.userId === userId;" return false?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm following along the [Discover Meteor tutorial](https://book.discovermeteor.com/chapter/editing-posts) and after commit 8-1 we add:

```
// Check that the userId specified owns the documents
ownsDocument = function(userId, doc) {
  return doc && doc.userId === userId;
}
```

What I don't understand is that doc and userId are not strictly equal (===), so why does this work?

For reference:

doc:

```
{ _id:       '1a2b3c4d',
  url:       'blahblah.com',
  title:     'blah blah',
  userId:    '0w9x8y7z',
  author:    'testuser',
  submitted: '...'}
```

doc.userId:

```
userId: 0w9x8y7z
```

userId:

```
userId: 0w9x8y7z
```

I get that `doc.userId === userId`, but why would `doc && doc.userId === userId` pass?

Comment: `doc` itself is evaluated as `true` (its an object; not 0, null, ""  or anything else that would evaluated as `false` in a boolean context) As its true the next test following `&&` is then evaluated.  (This is done as if `doc` were `null` (falsey) attempting to access a property `doc.userId ` would cause an error)

Comment: as @AlexK. says above, it doesn't evaluate to false, thus the statement continues to be evaluated. this is known as the short circuit technique. basically, it's a good idea to check that `doc` exists before you try and access one of its properties. if `doc` were undefined, it would return false without considering whether it (being undefined) had a property of userId and whether that is equal to the provided `userId`.

Comment: One clarification. If `doc` is `undefined`, then `undefined` will be returned, not `false`. This would be better written as `return !!doc && doc.userId === userId;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of your confusion appears to be that you interpret this:

```
if(doc && doc.userId === userId)
```

as "if both doc and doc.userId are equal to userId". This is not the case.

Each side of the `&&` is a separate condition altogether. It is the same as:

```
if(doc == true && doc.userId === userId)
```

Secondly, the `== true` part on the left side is redundant, so is often not included when checking if a variable is [truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript-values-where-value-is-true).

The reason for the [truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript-values-where-value-is-true) check is that you want to check that `doc` is not [falsey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript-values-where-value-is-true), before you try to access a property on it. Using a logical `AND`, if the left side does not evaluate to true, then the right side will not be executed. Without the check, if `doc` was [falsey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript-values-where-value-is-true) then an error would be produced for trying to access a property on a none object.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common idiom used in JavaScript, if you want to check that an object is not `undefined` (or otherwise [falsey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript-values-where-value-is-true)) before accessing one of its properties you can say:

```
obj && obj.prop
```

The [`&&` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) does not evaluate the second argument if the first argument is falsey, so this protects your code from trying to retrieve a property value from a variable whose value is undefined

So, the return statement in your example is equivalent to:

```
if (doc){
    return doc.userId;
} else {
    return doc;
}
```

Comment: Ohhhhh, so I'm checking that `doc` exists and THEN checking that `doc.userId = userId`. That makes so much more sense now. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [Operator Precedence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), you will see that equality (`==` / `===`) is of higher precedence than AND (`&&`), so this:

```
doc && doc.userId === userId
```

is parsed this way:

```
doc && (doc.userId === userId)
```

and not this one:

```
(doc && doc.userId) === userId
```

Then, since `doc` is truthy, the engine evaluates `doc.userId === userId` and returns that result.