# Could someone please explain the looping process to add new properties to an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop

I am very new to programming, so forgive me for being such a noob. Any input is much appreciated. The challenge asks to find the mode in an array of numbers. Here is the code:

```
function findMode(arr) {
  var c = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    c[arr[i]] = (c[arr[i]] || 0) + 1;
  }
  var mode;
  var max = 0;
  for (var e in c) {
    if (c[e] > max) {
      mode = e;
      max = c[e];
    }
  }
  return mode * 1;
}
```

So for example if you have an array of `[1,1,5,5,7,10,3,3,3,3]`, it makes an object of `{'1':2, '3':4, '5':2, '7':1, '10':1}`. The code below it( `for(e in c)`) I understand it. Function basically returns the mode which is 3. What I am confused about is the following code:

```
c[arr[i]] = (c[arr[i]] || 0) + 1;
```

This code is responsible for creating the following object:

```
{'1':2, '3':4, '5':2, '7':1, '10':1}
```

Can someone please explain how it does that? How does it make the list of objects and keep count of each object name? I am very confused by it.

Comment: FYI, using the code snippet makes only sense if your example produces any visible output.

Comment: @FelixKlingThank you my friend. As you can tell, I am VERY NEW to programming and stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 4):

`var a = b || c;` is a common idiom in JavaScript. What it means is:

1. if `b` is a *truthy* value, `a` will receive `b`.
2. if `b` is a *falsy* value, `a` will receive `c`.

(Look up "JavaScript truthy and falsy values" to understand this. Basically there are 6 things in JavaScript that are *falsy*. Everything else is *truthy*).

This is basically counting the number of occurrences of something.

If there wasn't a value assigned for `c[arr[i]]`, it will be `undefined`. Being `undefined`, the expression `(c[arr[i]] || 0)` would result in `0`, because `undefined` is a *falsy* value. Then, `0 + 1` results in `1`. `c[arr[i]]` is now `1`.

On the other hand, if there was a value assigned for `c[arr[i]]`, then `(c[arr[i]] || 0)` would result that same value (let's say, `1`, for instance). So `(c[arr[i]] || 0)` is then `1`, since `c[arr[i]]` is `1` and `1 || 0` would result in `1`, since `1` is a *truthy* value. Then you have `1 + 1` and `c[arr[i]]` is now `2`.

You are counting occurrences of something. You started with `0`, then `1`, then `2`.

Answer (score 2):

If you break it down, it does the same as:

```
var c = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var a = arr[i];
  // count item for the first time
  if (c[a] === undefined) {
    c[a] = 1;
  // increment count
  } else {
    c[a] = c[a] + 1;
  }
}
```

You can keep going:

```
if (!c[a]) {
  c[a] = 1
} else {
  c[a] += 1
}
```

And more:

```
c[a] = c[a] ? (c[a] + 1) : 1
```

Until you get:

```
c[a] = (c[a] + 1) || 1 // OR passes because NaN (hacky)
```

Which could also be expressed as:

```
c[a] = (c[a] || 0) + 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I understood it so well with your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break your code snippet down into its individual parts:

- `c[arr[i]]`: This code does the same thing that using the dot notation would do (like `arr.length`). It's referring to a place in the object- in this case, an element in `arr`. For example, if `arr = [3,6,8]`, and you say `c[arr[0]]`, you're trying to add this to the object: `3: ...`. For `c[arr[1]]`, you would be trying to add `6: ...` and so on. We have to use the brackets because we don't know what's at `arr[i]`.
- `=`: You know what that does, I'm hoping.
- `(c[arr[i]] || 0)`: This is saying, "if `c[arr[i]]` is a [falsy value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19839953/4097359) (like `false`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, etc.), then set `c[arr[i]]` to 0". If it was a truthy value (like `true`, `3`, `"string"`), then `c[arr[i]]` would be set to itself- in other words, it wouldn't change. If the left side of `||` is truthy, `c[arr[i]]` is set to that, otherwise, it's set to the right side of `||`, which is `0` in this case. [Here's a reference for how these *logical operators* work.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)
- `+1`: Regardless of what `(c[arr[i]] || 0)` evaluated to, add 1 to whatever's in `c[arr[i]]` now.

If you're into ES6/ES2015/whatever they're calling it now, `Map` is perfect for these kinds of problems:

```js
function findMode(arr) {
  let c = new Map();
  arr.forEach(elem => {
    c.set(elem, (c.get(elem) || 0) + 1);
  });
  let mode, max = 0;
  for (let [key, value] of c) {
    if (value > max) {
      mode = key;
      max = value;
    }
  }
  return mode;
}
findMode([1, 1, 5, 5, 7, 10, 3, 3, 3, 3]); // -> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c[arr[i]] = (c[arr[i]] || 0) + 1;
```

Piece by piece:

`c` is the name of the object which you can access the internal properties of using a `[]` instead of the usual `.` syntax you are probably familiar with in JS objects.

`arr` is the given array into the answer
`i` is the index in the for loop
`arr[i]` is a number in the list (eg 1)

`c[arr[i]]` means the value associated with the key `arr[i]` in object `c`. There is an `=` sign so we are assigning to that value

`c[arr[i]]` is also found on the other side of the equals sign so we are reading the value

And then we add one to it.

The `|| 0` basically means if `c[arr[i]]` is a "false" like value which in JS `null` is, then use `0` instead of `null`. This solves for the case where we haven't seen this number before.