# Why does using "0" with the ternary operator return the first value?

Tags: javascript, types, ternary-operator

I was playing around with JSconsole and found something strange. The value of `"0"` is false

```
"0" == false
=> true
```

The value of `false` when used in ternary returns the second value

```
false ? 71 : 16
=> 16
```

However the value `"0"` which equals `false` when used in ternary returns the first value.

```
"0" ? 8 : 10
=> 8
```

However, if you use `0` as the value, it returns the second value

```
0 ? 4 : 5
=> 5

0 == "0"
=> true
```

I'm afraid this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: `"0"` is a string that's not empty, i.e. not a falsy value

Comment: Then why does "0" equal false when using comparison `==`

Comment: `==` in Javascript doesn't make sense. `'' == 0`, `0 == '0'`, but `'' != '0'`. Don't assume that because `x == y`, `x` and `y` will behave remotely the same.

Comment: This is one of the more confusing features of Javascript. There are at least four (!) scenarios where a value can `== false` yet not be "falsey". I've been putting together a reference guide under the question [All falsey values in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript-values-where-value-is-true). I think I've got all of the falsey-related quirks and gotchas documented there... if I've missed any, please comment!

Comment: @CodesInChaos, you are mistaken: `!!"0"` evaluates to `true`. Agreed about `==`, though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`"0"` is a *string* of length`>0` which is `true`. Try

```
0 ? 8 : 10
```

and see. It will return `10`.

`==` does *type conversion* and hence when you do

```
"0" == false
```

it returns `true`. When you do

```
0 == "0" //true
```

It also returns true as again type conversion is taking place. Even though one is a `number` and the other one is a `string` it returns true. But if you use `===`, **no** type conversion is done and `0 === "0"` will return `false`.

A nice explanation of `==` & `===` is given ***[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/3894168)***.

From the ***[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)***:

> The equality operator(`==`) converts the operands if they are not of the same type, then applies strict comparison.
>
> The identity operator(`===`) returns *true* if the operands are strictly equal with no type conversion.

Comment: A non-zero length string.

Comment: When I typed in `"0" == false` I got true

Comment: @user4703663 `==` will internally do `type conversion`, so use `===`.

Comment: @user4703663 A very nice explanation of both is given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/3894168).

Answer (score 21):

Non-empty string is considered as truth value in conditional statements, conditional expressions and conditional constructs.

But when you compare a string with a number with `==`, some conversion will take place.

> When comparing a number and a string, **the string is converted to a**
>   **number value**. JavaScript attempts to convert the string numeric
>   literal to a Number type value. First, a mathematical value is derived
>   from the string numeric literal. Next, this value is rounded to
>   nearest Number type value.

And `==` don't have the **Transitive Property of Equality**:

you can't say `if a == b, b == c, then a == c`.

An example will be:

```
"0" == false // true
false == "\n" //true
```

and guess the result of `"0" == "\n"`? Yes, the result is `false`.

Comment: Some mention of `===` would make the answer stronger.

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid this is an example of why you should use `===` - plain old `==` performs type conversion. Try

```
"0"===false
```

Comment: But wait, `"0"===true` yields false either. This may not answer the question straightaway, I guess.

Comment: @TaoP.R. If you want to convert a value to a boolean in a way that respects how it acts in a ternary operator, use `!!value`. As in `!!"0" === true`.

Comment: @Random832 Would `Boolean()` be completely equivalent? (i.e. `Boolean(x) === !!x` for all values of `x`) - that's probably the more explicit/readable/obvious way.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript leads to tons of WTFs.

Check out "Javascript WTF" on YouTube...

Essentially, you are requesting a **conversion from string to boolean**.

This is defined as "string is not empty".

Whereas you assumed that javascript does string -> int -> boolean if the string happens to contain a number.

It's *sensible*. But these automatic conversions lead to programming errors, which is why I prefer typesafe languages (with compile time type checking) for larger projects.

For fun, try these:

```
("0" * 1) ? 71 : 16
("0" + false) ? 71 : 16
```