# Why is "0" is usually considered false but not with the ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, boolean-expression

Evaluating the following statements in a browser's javascript console yields the results shown:

```
"0" == 0       // true
"0" == false   // true
"0" == true    // false
 0 ? true : false      // false
"0" ? true : false     // true   ???? WHAT  ???
```

The first four make sense but not the last one.  Is this a bug?  If not, how is the "0" being typecast in order to make it appear truthy, but why does this only happen for the ternary operator and not equality operator?

(Tested in multiple browser consoles with same result.)

Comment: Never mind, I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670964/why-does-using-0-with-the-ternary-operator-return-the-first-value

Comment: A non-empty string is never false-y

Comment: Use `===` and there are no surprises like this. `"0" === false` is false as is right and proper.

Comment: Yes, it's confusing, so use === to do the equal test