# JavaScript: How '' == '0' // false and 0 == '' //true?

Tags: javascript

I am curious how

```
'' == '0'  // false
```

left side is a blank string and right side has string with value 0 so its fine its is false.

But

```
0 == ''    // true
```

how blank string equals to zero, both are typed different as well as value.

similar

```
false == 'false'   // false
```

left is false , but we are not equating (===) type of value , its just has value false so it should be true ? but why it is false.

Could we explain the same ?

Comment: http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3

Comment: Your first two snippets are not symmetrical in the first place.

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript

Comment: @ huan son : rarely saw such "stupid" way of answering question. No offense

Comment: @For -ve: I did research , but output is something confusing. don't have exact answer for the same. not much concern about -ve reputation if get better explanation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The left operand is of the type Number.
The right operand is of the type String.
    In this case, the right operand is coerced to the type Number:

```
0 == Number('')
which results in

0 == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The following values are always falsy:

- false 0 (zero)
- "" or '' (empty string)
- null
- undefined
- NaN (a special Number value meaning Not-a-Number!)

I found a nice table explaining what works and what not with the `==` operator.

[image]

[**Here**](http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/) is the link to the tables also containing `===` and `if()`.

Comment: Just because something is falsy does not explain the rules used when the `==` operator is applied.

Comment: "The empty string is a falsy value, the string containing 0 is not the integer 0 and not empty so the string is true" --- this is wrong.

Comment: "0 (zero) is a falsy value. An empty string ('') is a falsy value too" --- this is wrong as well.

Comment: Guys, please **STOP** trying to guess, check the specification **BEFORE** you give answer about language behaviour. Thank you for saving our time.

Comment: An empty string and an integer 0 is a falsy value. You forgot we are comparing with 2 equal signs, not 3. The 3rd equals sign compares the type too. In this case it doesn't.

Comment: Please check and make sure you understand the link http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3 **before** you continue this useless discussion. What you use as an argument is just nonsense.

Comment: And now it does not address the question in any way. The question was why `==` operator behaves like that. Whereas your answer mentions some term that is not directly relevant to that operator.