# array.length vs. array.length > 0

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there any difference between checking an array's length as a truthy value vs checking that it's > 0?

In other words is there any reason to use one of these statements over the other:

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
if (arr.length) {
}

if (arr.length > 0) {
}
```

Comment: if you know it's an array of objects (like a dom query result lib call), `if(arr[0])` works just fine too.

Comment: Warm welcome to the people arguing over this in code review

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`array.length` is fastest and shorter than `array.length > 0`. You can see difference of their speeds : http://jsperf.com/test-of-array-length

`if(array.length){...}` is similar to `if(0){...}` or `if(false){...}`

Comment: Interestingly enough `array.length` ran slower for me than `array.length > 0` in Chrome 59. Not sure how that's possible since intuitively it seems like it would be doing less.

Comment: Chrome VM optimises in different ways each new version. If you have to think what the compiler is doing behind, knowing V8 is written in C++ and C++ is typed, the array length which is a number is treated as a boolean expression so I would say that in some cases it does the equivalent of `Boolean(array.length)` when the `> 0` is not present. There are a lots of different values that can be true or false in javascript and they all require a check (null, false, undefined, 0, '', etc.)

Answer (score 23):

> Is there any difference between checking an array's length as a truthy value vs checking that it's > 0?

Since the value of `arr.length` can only be `0` or larger and since `0` is the only number that evaluates to `false`, there is no difference.

In general, `Boolean(n)` and `Boolean(n > 0)` yield different results for `n < 0`.

> In other words is there any reason to use one of these statements over the other

Only reasons related to code readability and understanding, not behavior.

Comment: +1 for that last sentence. You can do pretty much anything with JavaScript, even if it's stupid or hard to read. It takes a good developer to write readable code.

Comment: It's also debatable which of those is the more readable option. IMO it is `if (array.length)` but I know other people who prefer `if (array.length > 0)

Answer (score 11):

In javascript, they dont make a difference.

In the end, whatever is in between the `if` parenthesis will evaluate to a *truthy* or *falsey* value

For all possible falsey values, see [All falsey values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript)

If you wish to be more clear and explicit, use

```
if (arr.length > 0) {
}
```

If you wish to be less verbose, use

```
if (arr.length) {
}
```

Comment: To add emphasis to this answer, many developers choose clarity over being concise. It helps with code readability when scanning over it. Otherwise, there is no difference.

Comment: More explicit yes. More clear though is debatable.
In some cases, like this one, I think clarity is relatively equal with either option. Often I would go for the more verbose option but in this case I don't think it adds any value. I read it as "if the array has length", which is perfectly understandable IMO so I don't think the > 0 adds value. I think it actually just adds unnecessary noise, although maybe I've adapted to that over years of reading it without the > 0 so I can see how it would be easier that way for someone not used to it. (See, I'm usually pro verbosity :D)