# why null is not converted to a boolean value in a conditional statement?

Tags: javascript, boolean, comparison

Having the following test case: (find fiddle [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/5qct25hu/))

```
var a = new Date();
var b = null;
var c = {test: "test"};

if(a)
    console.log(a); //--- prints the current date

if(b)
    console.log('null'); //--- never reached

if(c)
    console.log('test'); //--- prints 'test'

console.log(a && b); //--- prints null
```

Knowing that

```
console.log(typeof null); //--- prints "object"
console.log(typeof c); //--- prints "object"
```

I expect the result of

```
console.log(a && b);
```

to be **false** and not **null** as it shown in the example.

Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I expect the result of
>
> ```
> console.log(a && b);
> ```
>
> to be `false` and not `null` as it shown in the example.

In many languages with `&&` and `||` operators (or `AND` and `OR`), the result is always a boolean, yes.* But JavaScript's `&&` and `||` are more useful than that: Their result is their left-hand operand's value or their right-hand operand's value, **not** coerced to boolean.

Here's how `&&` works:

1. Evaluate the left-hand operand.
2. If the value is *falsey* (coerces to `false` when we make it a boolean), return the value (not the coerced value)
3. If the value from #2 is *truthy*, evaluate and return the right-hand value (uncoerced)

The *falsey* values are `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`. Everything else is *truthy*.

So for instance

```
console.log(0 && 'hi');    // 0
```

...shows `0` because `0` is falsey. Note it resulted in `0`, not `false`. Similarly, the result here:

```
console.log(1 && 'hello'); // hello
```

...is `'hello'` because the right-hand side isn't coerced at all by `&&`.

`||` works similarly (I call it the [*curiously-powerful OR operator*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html)): It evaluates the left-hand side and, if that's *truthy*, takes that as its result; otherwise it evaluates the right-hand side and takes *that* as its result.

The only time you get `true` or `false` from `&&` or `||` is if the selected operand is *already* a boolean.

---

* Of course, many (but not all) of those languages (Java, C#) also require that the operands to `&&` and `||` already be booleans. C's an exception, it does some coercion, but still has the result of the operands as a boolean (or if you go back far enough, an int that will be 1 or 0).

Comment: Either your writing is confusing or I'm more tired than I thought I am. What are the "many languages" where `new Date() && null` evaluates to `false` ? Do I misunderstand you ?

Comment: @DenysSéguret: In many languages, `&&` and `||` always result in a boolean. In most of those languages, of course, the operands to `&&` and `||` are required to be booleans, coercion isn't done (C#, Java, ...). C's an example where coercion is done (like JavaScript, though the rules are different), but the result is a boolean (unlike JavaScript). I'll reword that opening for greater clarity.

Answer (score 4):

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators):

> `expr1 && expr2` : Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; **otherwise, returns expr2**

`new Date` can't be converted to `false` (it's not [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)), so `b` is returned.

Comment: how do I know what can be converted to **false** and what can't? is there any table showing the types that can be converted to false?

Comment: @BeNdErR: Values that coerce to false in conditions are called "falsey values." Here's the list: `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`. Everything else is *truthy*. So *all* non-`null` object references are truthy.

Comment: @BeNdErR See the MDN (again) on "truthy": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: There's also another answer on stackoverflow that provides the full falsey list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript

Comment: @BeNdErR Convert the expression to true/false by negating it and then use De-Morgan's law like `console.log(!(!a || !b));` or also `console.log(!!a && !!b)` should work

Comment: In addition to this: Since you use your `a && b` statement within a console.log(), it's return value get's casted to a `string`, not a `boolean`. Since `a && b` returns `null` (`b` being `null`), it get's casted to `"null"`. If you used the same statement in an `if statement`, the return value would get casted to a `boolean`, i.e. `false`.

Answer (score 0):

From MDN:

> Logical AND (&&)  expr1 && expr2  Returns expr1 if it can be converted
>   to false; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean
>   values, && returns true if both operands are true; otherwise, returns
>   false.

[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)