# Understanding recursive functions combined with logical operators in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

In [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/03_functions.html#p_KNlnW1VpW2), the following example is given as a recursive function:

```
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(start, history) {
    if (start == target)
      return history;
    else if (start > target)
      return null;
    else
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}

console.log(findSolution(24));
```

A good explanation is given after, but I'm having trouble understanding why the

```
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
```

bit works. Why can you have an `||` without, it seems to me in any case, a boolean being worked on? How does `find()` know to "come back" and to this part of the function and "try again" with `start * 3` when it gets to a branch in which `start > target` and thus is given a `null`?

Comment: `||` is a [short-circuit operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: `find()` returns the history, or null. Remember that null is a [falsey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript), so it will evaluate to false, and if the function does not return null, but a history it will return true (truthy value). That's why it can evaluate and return true or false. As mentioned above, `||` is a short-circuit operator. Meaning that if the expression to the left of the `||` evaluates to true, it won't evaluate the expression to the right. The way it 'knows' where/how to come back, you will need to read a little about call stacks in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a mentor step me through the problem.

When `findSolution(target)` is called, it calls `find(1,"1")`. The reason `||` works is because, if the target is example `24`, because (as elclanrs pointed out) `||` is short circuit, only `find(start + 5...)` calls will be performed until `start = 26`. Upon this iteration, `start > target`, and thus it will `return null`. The previous call, in which `start = 21`, will receive a NULL, which `||` treats as `false`, which causes it to `find(start * 3...)`, which will also result in a `NULL` return, which will go back to an iteration in which `start = 16`, and so on.