# Results of "truthy" and "falsey" is confusing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scripting, programming-languages

I am learning JavaScript basics. I am confused about the results of "truthy" and "falsey". Can anyone tell the reason for this?

```
myVariable = undefined ? "truthy" : "falsey";
```

The result is **"falsey"**.

```
myVariable = typeOf someUndefinedVariable ? "truthy" : "falsey";
```

The result is **"truthy"**.

I expected "falsey" instead for the second result. Why did I get "truthy"? I am really confused.

Comment: Under what environment are you running this code? For me your second snippet raises an exception and so `myVariable` will never be assigned either `"truthy"` or `"falsey"`. Are you sure that `someUndefinedVariable` is not defined?

Comment: @PeterHorne  I am using just notepad++,yes I am sure that someUndefinedVariable is not defined

Answer (score 3):

`typeof` returns the type *name* of the value, which is always a *non-empty string*. A non-empty string is *truthy*.

```
> typeof someUndefinedVariable
"undefined"
> typeof (typeof someUndefinedVariable)
"string"
> Boolean("undefined")
true
```

See also [All falsey values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll explain what happened in the code you've shown, just to be sure you understand it. Maybe you already understand the first half, but since you say you are very confused, I will assume you don't.

```js
myVariable = undefined ? "truthy" : "falsey";
// result: "falsey"
```

Here you are looking at a value, `undefined`, and asking a question: is it truthy or falsey? Based on that you choose a string. Then you store that string into `myVariable`. It is effectively the same as this code:

```js
var myVariable;
if (undefined) {
    myVariable = 'truthy';
} else {
    myVariable = 'falsey';
}
```

Since `undefined` is always falsey, at the end, `myVariable` contains the string `'falsey'`.

Here is your second snippet of code:

```js
myVariable = typeOf someUndefinedVariable ? "truthy" : "falsey";
// result: "truthy"
```

First, I must point out that `typeOf` is not a valid function or operator in any Javascript runtime I know of. I will assume that was a typo, and you meant to use `typeof` instead. The code above, as written, should throw a syntax error. Corrected, we have...

```js
myVariable = typeof someUndefinedVariable ? "truthy" : "falsey";
// result: "truthy"
```

And for clarity, let's rewrite it as an if/else:

```js
var myVariable;
if (typeof someUndefinedVariable) {
    myVariable = 'truthy';
} else {
    myVariable = 'falsey';
}
```

As another answerer has [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35133020/2449905), typeof will always return, *as a string*, the type of the symbol you give to it.

```js
typeof(someUndefinedVariable);
"undefined"
```

And since all strings except the empty string are truthy, you get truthy back.

There are only 7 falsey values in Javascript.

```
false               Boolean false
undefined           If a symbol is not defined at all
null                A defined symbol, but it has no value inside
0                   Numeric positive 0
-0                  Numeric negative 0
'' or ""            Empty string
NaN                 Magic value "Not a Number"
```

**All other values in Javascript are truthy.**

- any string except empty string
- any number except 0
- any array, **including** an empty array
- any object, **including** an empty object
- functions
- etc ...