# Understanding JavaScript Truthy and Falsy

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain JavaScript Truthy and Falsy, using the below sample data. I have read other threads but still confused.

```
var a = 0;

var a = 10 == 5;

var a = 1; 

var a = -1;
```

From my understanding, I believe that `var a = 1;` is the only truthy and the rest are falsy - is this correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Results of "truthy" and "falsey" is confusing in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132997/results-of-truthy-and-falsey-is-confusing-in-javascript)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

> From my understanding, I believe that var a = 1; is the only truthy and the rest are falsy’s - is this correct?

**No.**

1. > var a = 0;

   Number zero is **falsy**. However, note that the string zero `"0"` is truthy.
2. > var a = 10 == 5;

   This is same as `var a = (10 == 5);`, so this is **falsy**.
3. > var a = 1;
   >
   > var a = -1;

   Any non-zero number including negative numbers is **truthy**.

Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

> In JavaScript, a *truthy* value is a value that translates to *true* when evaluated in a Boolean context. All values are *truthy* unless they are defined as *falsy* (i.e., except for `false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and `NaN`).

**List of falsy values in JavaScript:**<sup>[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)</sup>

1. `false`
2. `null`
3. `undefined`
4. `0`
5. `NaN`
6. `''`, `""`, ``` `` ```(Empty template string)
7. `document.all`
8. `0n`: BigInt
9. `-0`

Comment: Why on earth is `document.all` falsy??

Comment: @Claudiu _`document.all` has been used for browser detection in the past and the HTML specification defines a willful violation of the ECMAScript standard here to keep compatibility with legacy code (`if (document.all) { // Internet Explorer code here }` or using `document.all` without checking its presence first: `document.all.foo`)._

Comment: @Tushar: That is wonderfully... brilliant and horrible at the same time.

Comment: Speaking of dupes, I'm pretty sure this one is covered as well :)

Comment: Hi @DaveNewton, Other conditions except `var a = 10 == 5;` are definitely covered in the _so dupe_. So, IMO should not be closed as dupe.

Comment: @Claudiu https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350142/why-is-document-all-falsy

Answer (score 29):

There's a simple way to check, which you can use now and forever:

```
function truthyOrFalsy(a) {
    return a ? "truthy" : "falsy";
}
```

To wit:

```
> truthyOrFalsy(0)
"falsy"
> truthyOrFalsy(10 == 5)
"falsy"
> truthyOrFalsy(1)
"truthy"
> truthyOrFalsy(-1)
"truthy"
```

Also see [a list of all falsey values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19839953/15055).

Answer (score 8):

Truthy -> Value that resolve to true in boolean context

Falsy  -> Value that resolve to false in boolean context

For better understanding, `falsy` values are given below.

1. `false`
2. `0`
3. `empty string`
4. `null`
5. `undefined`
6. `NaN`

Answer (score 4):

*The below answer might help someone.*

As well as a type, each value also has an inherent Boolean value, generally known as either truthy or falsy. Some of the rules are a little bizarre, so understanding the concepts and effect on comparison helps when debugging JavaScript applications.

**The following values are always falsy:**

- false
- 0 (zero)
- -0 (minus zero)
- 0n (BigInt zero)
- '', "", `` (empty string)
- null
- undefined
- NaN

**Everything else is truthy. That includes:**

- '0' (a string containing a single zero)
- 'false' (a string containing the text “false”)
- [] (an empty array)
- {} (an empty object)
- function(){} (an “empty” function)

A single value can therefore be used within conditions. For example:

`if (value) { // value is truthy } else { // value is falsy // it could be false, 0, '', null, undefined or NaN }`

Answer (score 3):

**FALSY**

- false
- 0 (zero)
- "", '', `` (empty strings)
- null
- undefined
- NaN (not a number)

*note : Empty array ([]) is not* falsy

**TRUTHY**

- Everything that is not FALSY

Answer (score 1):

one more check version:

```
function truthyOrFalsy(a) {
    return (a && "truthy") || "falsy";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In short there are only 6 types of falsy values:
You can use this snippet to test them:

```
function isTruthy(val){
    if(val){
        console.log(val + ' is Truthy');
    }else{
        console.log(val + ' is falsy');
    }
}
    

// all below are truthy
isTruthy (true)
isTruthy ({})
isTruthy ([])
isTruthy (42)
isTruthy ("0")
isTruthy ("false")
isTruthy (new Date())
isTruthy (-42)
isTruthy (12n)
isTruthy (3.14)
isTruthy (-3.14)
isTruthy (Infinity)
isTruthy (-Infinity)

//all below are falsy
isTruthy(0);
isTruthy("");
isTruthy(false);
isTruthy(NaN);
isTruthy(null);
isTruthy(undefined);
```

Refer this site for details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to check Falsy Value and True value

```
function truthyOrFalsy(val){
  if(val){
    console.log (`${val} is truthy`);
  } else{
    console.log (`${val} is falsy`);
  }   
}
```

**Check all FALSY value:**

```
truthyOrFalsy(false);      //Output: false is falsy
truthyOrFalsy(null);       //Output: null is falsy
truthyOrFalsy(0);          //Output: 0 is falsy
truthyOrFalsy('');         //Output:  is falsy  [blank refers to '']
truthyOrFalsy(NaN);        //Output: NaN is falsy
truthyOrFalsy(undefined);  //Output: undefined is falsy
```

> Please note that `undefined` is not explicitly used to set as value.
> Some common scenarios will create undefined:
>
> - Parameter defined in function but not passed argument in callback function.
> - If nothing returns in function
> - If accessing to an object property/method which is not defined
> - If accessing to an array element which is not defined

```
function add(num1, num2){   
    console.log(num1, num2);    
}
const result = add(44);
console.log(result);
//Output: 44 undefined
//        undefined

const car = {color:"Blue", price: 200000};
console.log(car.category);
//Output: undefined
arrColors = ["Blue", "Sky", "Purple"];
console.log(arrColors[5]);
//Output: undefined
```

**Check all TRUTHY values**

> All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy.
>
> Although `' ', '0', -1, []` could be enlisted to be checked.

```
truthyOrFalsy(' ');      //Output: is truty     [blank refers to space inside 
                         //                       quote ]
truthyOrFalsy('0');       //Output: 0 is truty 
truthyOrFalsy([]);          //Output: is truty  [blank refers to an empty array]
truthyOrFalsy(-1);         //Output: -1 is truty
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to evaluate whether something is truthy or falsy that I like to use is

```
function truthyOrFalsy(a) {
  return !!a;
}
```