# Trying to understand .some() in javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This is a portion of code from https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4183330

I am trying to understand how `names.some(function(d)...})` works.

1. Shouldn't the anonymous function passed to `.some()` return a conditional statement that "countires" can be evaluated against?
2. When will `names.some(..)` return true or false?
3. Why doesn't `d.name = n.name` create "name" property in "countries" without "return"?

```js
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "world-110m.json")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "world-country-names.tsv")
    .await(ready);

function ready(error, world, names) {
    var countries = topojson.feature(world,world.objects.countries).features
    countries = countries.filter(function(d) {
        return names.some(function(n) {
                  if (d.id == n.id) return d.name = n.name;
     });
})
```

Answer (score 3):

1) Since it's using `names.some()`, the function is testing each element of `names`, not `countries`.

2) When any of the names have an `id` that matches `d.id` and `n.name` is not empty.

3) It will always create the property. But if there's no `return`, `.some()` doesn't get a truth value that it can evaluate.

It would probably be easier to understand if they'd written:

```
return names.some(function(n) {
    if (d.id == n.id) {
        d.name = n.name;
        return d.name;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

`return d.name = n.name;` combines the assignment and return value into a single statement. And the code is making use of the fact that functions implicitly return `undefined` when they don't execute a `return` statement, and `undefined` is falsey.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarification. I am a bit confused since the code inside .some() does not have a explicit  statement "return true". So, returning a variable (d.name) also implies true? Under which topic should I look into to understand this concept?

Comment: It just cares if the value is *truthy*. Any non-empty string is truthy.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642809/understanding-javascript-truthy-and-falsy