# If an array is truthy in JavaScript, why doesn't it equal true?

Tags: javascript, arrays, comparison, javascript-objects

I have the following code snippet:

```
if([]) {
  console.log("first is true");
}
```

The `console` says `first is true` which means `[]` is true. Now I am wondering why this:

```
if([] == true) {
  console.log("second is true");
}
```

and this:

```
if([] === true) {
  console.log("third is true");
}
```

are not `true`. If the console logged `first is true` in the first snippet, that means `[]` should be true, right? So why do the latter two comparisons fail? [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/j3bzkyvq/1/) is the fiddle.

Comment: [Understanding javascript truthy and falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642809/understanding-javascript-truthy-and-falsy)

Comment: You cant test an array for truthiness. Are you trying to test if it exists?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is by specification. By the [ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/), any object that is implicitly [coerced into a boolean](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toboolean) is true; that means objects are truthy. Inside of an `if` statement, the condition, once evaluated and if not already boolean, is coerced into a boolean. Thus, doing:

```
if([]) { 
  ... 
}
```

`[]` is truthy when coerced to a boolean and is true.

On the other hand, when you try to compare two values of differing types with abstract comparison, `==`, the engine must internally go through an algorithm to reduce the values to similar types, and ultimately integers that it can compare. In [Section 7.2.12 of the specification](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) on the steps for Abstract Equality Comparison *`x == y`*, it states:

> #### 7.2.12 Abstract Equality Comparison
>
> The comparison *x == y*, where *x* and *y* are values, produces **true** or **false**. Such a comparison is performed as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> 9. If [Type](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*y*) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison *x ==* [ToNumber](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber)(*y*).

Thus, the `y` operand (in this case `true`) is converted to 1 by coercion with `ToNumber` since it is a boolean, and `[] == 1` is false because:

> 11. If [Type](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*x*) is Object and [Type](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*y*) is either String, Number, or Symbol, then
>       return the result of the comparison [ToPrimitive](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toprimitive)(*x*) *== y*.

This will convert the `x` operand to a string with the `toString` method of the array, which is `""` for an empty array in this case. After going through `ToPrimitive`, it will result in:

```
if("" == 1) {
  ...
}
```

And finally:

> 7. If [Type](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*x*) is String and [Type](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(*y*) is Number,
>      return the result of the comparison [ToNumber](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber)(*x*) *== y*.

Thus, `ToNumber` of an empty string `""` is 0 and you get:

```
if(0 == 1) {
  ...
}
```

And 0 does not equal 1, thus it is false. Remember that just because something is truthy, **does not make it equal to true**. Just try `Symbol() == true` or `({}) == true`.

The final comparison, with `===` is [*strict comparison*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison), and **does not coerce any operands** and will return false if both operands are not the same type. Since the left operand is an object (an array) and the right is a number, the comparison evaluates to false.

Answer (score 1):

You have force type coercion before making a Boolean equity check with the Object types.

while `"" == false // <- true` or `0 == false // <- true` works out well

with the Object types it doesn't

```
null == false // <- false
```

so you better do like

`!!null === false // <- true` or `!![] === true // <- true`

Answer (score 0):

This is *strict equality*. It meas that both operands should be the *same thing*. In the case of object, they should be exactly the same object. Comparison between object with the same structure and the same values will fail, they need to be reference to the same object to success.

```
if([]===true){
  console.log("third is true");
}
```

In case of operands of different types, than the comparison between them becomes *strict*. This leads to the case above.

```
if([]==true){
  console.log("second is true");
}
```

Also, in the first `if` statement, `[]` is automatically casted to boolean true.

Comment: I really don't think this actually answers the question though; they're asking if `[]` is truthy why `[]==true` isn't true.

Answer (score 0):

`Boolean([])` is trying to ascertain whether the operand is truthy or not. Similarly, `if([]) console.log('truthy')` is checking whether the expression is truthy or not.

However, `true == []` does not immediately decide to check truthiness. Instead, it follows the `==` [weak equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality) checking rules.

The rule for `true == []` is:

> If one of the operands is an object and the other is a primitive,
> convert the object to a primitive.

Objects (including arrays) are converted into primitives by calling the `@@toPrimitive` method on the object. This method does not exist on regular arrays and objects, but will exist if you add it to an object or declare it as a method of the class of an object.

During the weak equality type coercion, the hint sent to the `@@toPrimitive` method is 'default'. However, in other situations, a different hint is provided, allowing the object to coerce to different primitives in different situations.

```js
const a = []

const b = []

b[Symbol.toPrimitive] = function (hint) {
  if(hint==='number') return 3;
  if(hint==='string') return 'hello'
  else return false; // happens when hint is 'default'
}

const log = x=>console.log(x)

log(a==true)    // false   - a has no toPrimitive function
log(a==false)   // false   - a has no toPrimitive function
log(b==true)    // false   - toPrimitive returns false
log(b==false)   // true    - toPrimitive returns false
log(!b)         // false   - checks for truthiness, and objects are truthy
log(Boolean(b)) // true    - checks for truthiness, and objects are truthy
log(b==3)       // false   - toPrimitive with hint=default returns false
log(Number(b))  // 3       - toPrimitive with hint=number returns 3
log(b=='hello') // false   - toPrimitive with hint=default returns false
log(String(b))  // 'hello' - toPrimitive with hint=string returns 'hello'
log(+b)         // 3       - `+` calls toPrimitive with hint=number,
                //           which returns 3
log(b+"")       // 'false' - toPrimitive with hint=default returns false
log(`${b}`)     // 'hello' - template literals call toPrimitive with
                //           hint=string, which returns 'hello'
```