# Javascript coercion true value and empty object

Tags: javascript

I try to understand why this happens:

```
console.log(Boolean(true)); //true
console.log(Boolean({})); //true
```

but

```
console.log(true == {}); //false
```

Is that even comparable?

I've read about type coercion and step by step process but still don't get this case.

Is my way of thinking right? Does coercion work as I wrote below?

```
true == {}
1 == {}
1 == [object Object]
false
```

Does JS stop because JS doesn't convert [object Object] to number value, so it returs false?

Comment: No, of course it's not comparable. `Boolean(2)` is true and `Boolean(3)` is true, but `2 == 3` is false.

Comment: Truthy means it *converts to `true`* not that it's *equal to `true`*.

Comment: I posted an answer to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75513245/5898421