# Trying to Understand this JavaScript For Loop with Ternary Operator

Tags: javascript

```
var res = '\n', i, j;
for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {                
    for (j = 1; j <= 15; j++) {
        res += (i * j) % 8 ? ' ' : '*';
    }
    res += '\n';
}
alert(res);
```

(Copy / Pasted from Object-Oriented JavaScript - Third Edition, Ved Antani, Stoyan Stefanov)

Trying to understand this loop.
I understand what's happening but not why.

```
res += (i * j) % 8 ? ' ' : '*';
```

I'm reading the ternary operator as follows.

- boolean expression: `(i * j) % 8`
- execute if true: concatenate space with `res`
- execute if false: concatenate asterisk with `res`

On the first iteration, when it comes to the inner loop, it only outputs '*', when the modulo is 0, all other times it outputs ' '.

Why does it do this?

Also, don't understand  the first line. What is the following doing?

```
var res = '\n', i, j;
```

What is the purpose of assigning the variable `res` to 3 values.

In the console it works fine without this line.

Comment: This is a an exact copy / paste from a book. Object-Oriented JavaScript - Third Edition,  Ved Antani, Stoyan Stefanov

Comment: `(i * j) % 8` isn't a boolean expression, it's a ([remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_())) mathematical operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var res = '\n', i, j;
```

These are three vars, written down in a confusing way:

```
var res = '\n'; // newline
var i;
var j;
```

In one line:

```
var i, j, res = '\n';
```

---

The script runs OK. I replaced the space with a dash, this is the result:

```
-------*-------
---*---*---*---
-------*-------
-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
-------*-------
---*---*---*---
-------*-------
```

If `i=1`, `j=i`, then `i*j%8` is not 0, thus true, which results in a dash. First line, you see seven dashes, then a *, etc.

Comment: So, if the result of a modulo operation is 0, then it is equal of false?

Comment: If modulo = 0, the result is false, it displays *. Test at http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/javascript-tester.html

Comment: @Doej2017 `0` is a falsy value. [Learn more about truthy/falsy values here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642809/understanding-javascript-truthy-and-falsy)

Answer (score 0):

It's running all the multiplications from 1*1 to 1*14 all the way to 6*1 to 6*14. As you already pointed out only if the modulo of said multiplication is zero it's adding a `*` to the `res` string. In the range of 1 to 14 the only time this is true is for 8.

You could add something to your inner block to visualize and aid you with understanding. An example would be:

```
console.log("i:", i, " j:", j, " multiplication:", i*j, "mod8:", (i*j)%8)
```

As a complete example this would look like this:

```
var res = '\n', i, j;
for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {                
    for (j = 1; j <= 15; j++) {
        res += (i * j) % 8 ? ' ' : '*';
        console.log("i:", i, " j:", j, " multiplication:", i*j, "mod8:", (i*j)%8)
    }
    res += '\n';
}
alert(res);
```