# Why do I get a different output when using an if statement in filter as oppose to just return

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and I am learning a little about High Order Functions. I was wondering if someone can tell me why:

```
function filter_list(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(item) {
    return typeof(item) == 'number';   
  });
}
// input = [1,'a','b',0,15] output = [1,0,15]
```

But

```
function filter_list(l) {
  return l.filter(function(item){
    if (typeof item == "number") {
      return item;
    }
  });
}
// input = [1,'a','b',0,15] output = [1,15]
```

I am having a hard time seeing the difference.

Comment: so what was the essuy

Comment: `0` is falsey. So when you return `0`, it will be treated as `return false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Filter

Filter returns a value if a condition is `true` and ignores it if it is `false`

```js
function filter(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(x) {
    return x
  })
}

const booleans = [false, false, true]


// this logs only "true"
console.log(filter(booleans))
```

## Truthy and Falsy

Additional to `true` and `false` there is `truthy` and `falsy`. This means that values evaluat to true or false in condition statements. You can read more on [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

```js
function getBooleanValue(value) {
  return !!value
}

console.log('1 gets cast to:', getBooleanValue(1))
console.log('0 gets cast to:', getBooleanValue(0))
```

## Your Code

The second code snippet didn't returns the `0` because it gets cast to false. To get the expected array you have to change the return value from `item` to `true`

```js
function filter_list(l) {
  return l.filter(function(item) {
    if (typeof item == "number") {
      return true;
    }
    return false
  });
}

console.log(filter_list([1, 'a', 'b', 0, 15]))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the 'beauty' of javascript. At your first example you return a boolean in your filter. the type of item is equal to number or it isn't

In the second example you return the item itself. So you return 1, 0 and 15. Because 1 is true and 0 is false in programming, javascript sees the returning 0 as a filter failure. So it is filtered. In other words, everything different from 0 is true, and 0 is false.

Answer (score 0):

In the second case:

```
function filter_list(l) {
  return l.filter(function(item){
    if (typeof item == "number") {
      return item;
    }
  });
}
```

`item` 's value is used to filter or not itself. When `item` is worth `0`, it's equivalent to `false` therefore, it's not included in the result. The function passed to `filter` expects a boolean result, if you do not return a boolean, you have to understand how javascript will interprete it.

Check it by yourself, `0` is equivalent `false`, therefore, if you return `0`, the element is going to be filtered:

```js
console.log(false == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter checks for Boolean values, it will take 0 and 1 as true and false, so if false == 0, the return 0 wont work.

```js
console.log(filter_list([1,'a','b',0,15]));

function filter_list(l) {
  return l.filter(function(item){
    if (typeof item == "number") {
      return item;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because JavaScript has `falsy` values. Javascript takes `null`, `undefined`, `0` & `false` as `falsy`.

```
function filter_list(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(item) {
    return typeof(item) == 'number';   
  });
}
// input = [1,'a','b',0,15] output = [1,0,15]
```

in this function you return `boolean` after comparing type, in which case each item that returns `true` in comparison is selected.

while in this function you are returning `values` instead of `result of comparison`, since `0` is `falsy` value it doesn't get selected for your filtered list.

```
function filter_list(l) {
  return l.filter(function(item){
    if (typeof item == "number") {
      return item;
    }
  });
}
// input = [1,'a','b',0,15] output = [1,15]
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter expects you to provide a boolean variable. This is done in your first example. The second example is just possible because Javascript is not using static types. The item `0` interpreted as boolean is `false`. So if you do `return 0`,  filter does not append the item.

Answer (score 0):

The two examples you have provided are not at all equivalent.

In the first example you are returning the result of evaluating the expression `typeof(item) == 'number'` which will either be `true` or `false` depending.

In the second you have *three* fairly different possibilities.

The first two are covered by the `if` statement: if the type of the item is number you are returning the item itself which may be 'falsey' (zero or NaN) and thus fail the filter or 'truthy' (anything but zero or NaN).

But there's *also* an implicit return of `undefined` if the type of item is not number. This doesn't have an impact in a filter because `undefined` is falsey, but you will likely get unexpected results using copying this pattern to use elsewhere and it should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `Array.prototype.filter()` creates a new array with all elements for which the test function returns a *truthy* value (see here: [Understanding JavaScript Truthy and Falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642809/understanding-javascript-truthy-and-falsy))

And because `0` is *falsy* it's not part of the returned array in the second sample.