# If (myVar != "undefined")

Tags: javascript

I wanted to check whether an item in localWebstorage was not yet given a value. I tried doing this by:

```
    //Change localStorage.intervalSetting from 'Undefined' to 'Never'
    function initialIntervalSetting() {
        var getValue = localStorage.intervalSetting;
        if (typeof getValue === undefined) {
            localStorage.intervalSetting = "option1";
            alert("Changed the localWebstorage item from undefined to "option1");
        }
        else {
            alert("JavaScript thinks that the item is not undefined");
        }
    }
```

This does not work, HOWEVER.. The question was asked here:
[How to check for "undefined" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript#) and someone answered:

```
        if (typeof getValue != "undefined") {
            localStorage.intervalSetting = "option1";
        }
```

They suggested replacing === with !=
For some reason, this works- How???
Shouldn't (getValue != "undefined") return false because != means NOT EQUAL??

Comment: `typeof` returns a **string**

Comment: Undefined is not a string though... is it!?

Comment: `if (getValue === undefined)` -- no need to check the type of any vars.

Comment: `if (typeof getValue === undefined) {` is never true ... `if (typeof getValue != "undefined") {` is true if `getValue` is **not** undefined

Comment: [undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) is a primitive

Comment: @demonhunter24 `typeof` returns a *string* representing the *type* of its argument. The string representation of the type of the expression `undefined` is the string `"undefined"`.

Comment: Does this mean that my second code example is asking if getValue if NOT a string? ..and therefore pays NO attention to what the string actually says?

Comment: Say getvalue is indeed undefined, using typeof on it will return the string "undefined" exactly like if you declare `let myvar = "undefined";` so your if statement is never true, because "undefined" is of type string and === checks the type as well, also the string "undefined" is not undefined, there is actually a value in there which just happen to be "undefined"

Comment: Doing `console.log(typeof undefined);` in the browser console might shed some light on what's going on. Result is `"undefined"`. Of course `console.log(typeof typeof undefined);` is `"string"`. *Head explodes*

Answer (score 1):

In your code you compared typeof getValue with the literal type undefined. Since typeof actually gives you a string, you should compare this value to the string "undefined".

Either

```
if (typeof getValue !== "undefined")
```

Or

```
if (getValue !== undefined)
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a "truthy" check. This will check if the object is null or undefined. You can do this by just checking your `getValue`.

```
if(getValue) {
    // not undefined
}
```

Another SO post for reference: [Understanding JavaScript Truthy and Falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642809/understanding-javascript-truthy-and-falsy?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: what if getValue is **ZERO**? ... or empty string?

Comment: This might be risky if `0` is a potential `getValue` value. `(getValue === undefined)` might be more accurate.

Comment: If 0 is a valid value that you want, you can add that to the condition.

Comment: Alternatively you can do what ggorlen is suggesting, `if (getValue === undefined) {...}`, but that will not account for null values.

Comment: OP isn't asking to check for `null`. The question is specific about "not having been given a value", which is `undefined`. `0`, `""` and `null` all need to be explicitly set on a var AFAIK.

Comment: Checking for undefined explicitly and disregarding other potential "non-value" values is just begging for problems. You are free to do as you want, but what you want is not always what you need.