# Filtering even numbers from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I would like to filter an array containing zeros (`0`) whilst capturing them too:

```js
var arr1 = [-200, -163, -26, -4, 0, 7, 76];

var evens = arr1.filter(function(x) {
  if (x % 2 === 0 || x === 0) {
    return x;
  }
})

console.log(evens);
```

Why do I *NOT* get zero back in my `evens` array? If zero is not classed as even, shouldn't my:

```
|| x === 0
```

statement catch the zero?

Comment: This is not how [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) works. The callback needs to return a boolean.

Comment: You want to return true rather than x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding JavaScript Truthy and Falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642809/understanding-javascript-truthy-and-falsy)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to return `true` or `false` from the [**Array#filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function. Based on the return value it will populate the returned array. Because conditions return `boolean`, you can just set the return value to the condition.

```js
var arr1 = [-200, -163, -26, -4, 0, 7, 76];

var evens = arr1.filter(function(x) {
   return x % 2 === 0;
})

console.log(evens);
```

Even more shorter syntax with arrow function

```js
var arr1 = [-200, -163, -26, -4, 0, 7, 76];

var evens = arr1.filter(x => x % 2 === 0);

console.log(evens);
```

Answer (score 3):

Return `true/false` from inside of `filter`:

```js
var arr1= [-200,-163, -26, -4, 0, 7,76];

var evens = arr1.filter(function(x){
  return x%2 === 0 || x === 0
})

console.log(evens);
```

In your code when you return `0`, `filter` will consider it *"falsy"* and hence you don't get 0 inside your filtered Array.

Answer (score 1):

Because `0` is considered a *"falsy"* value.

Your filter function is essentially returning `false` for `0` and filtering it from the array.

Check [this](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/) out for a deeper look.

Answer (score 0):

Array filter expects return as boolean value not number
If you need value in result it should be true else false;
0 is considered a false value.
you can return true in your function

```js
var arr1 = [-200, -163, -26, -4, 0, 7, 76];

var evens = arr1.filter(function(x) {
  if (x % 2 === 0 || x === 0) {
    return true;
  }
})

console.log(evens);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myEvennessFilter = (args) => args.filter(elem => (elem % 2) === 0);
console.log(myEvennessFilter([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]));
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it Run Up to 25% Faster, replace `elem % 2 == 0` with `(elem & 1) === 0`:

```js
// how to filter out even numbers using filter() in js
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
let even_numbers = numbers.filter(elem => elem%2 == 0)
```