# How can I remove even numbers from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to remove the even numbers for this array

```js
function removeEvens(numbers) {

}

/* Do not modify code below this line */

const oddNumbers = removeEvens([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
console.log(oddNumbers, `<-- should equal [1, 3, 5]`);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript - Filtering even numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51876350/javascript-filtering-even-numbers)

Answer (score 4):

The first step is how you check for evens - you can do this using the modulus operator (`%`) to see if the remainder when divided by 2 is 0, meaning that the number is even. Next you can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array to include only the numbers which pass this test:

```js
function removeEvens(numbers) {
    return numbers.filter(n => n % 2 !== 0); // if a number is even, remove it
}

const oddNumbers = removeEvens([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
console.log(oddNumbers);
```

Comment: Is 3.1 even? :)

Comment: @Joundill well it wasn't clearly specified whether there can be floats in the Array, but I updated my answer to not make this assumption. Although, it doesn't even make sense to be checking for the parity of an irrational number so I'm sure this won't have an effect

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do this with one line.

```js
function removeEvens(numbers) {
    return numbers.filter(n => n % 2 !== 0);
}


const oddNumbers = removeEvens([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
console.log(oddNumbers, '<-- should equal [1, 3, 5]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```js
function removeEvens(numbers) {
  return numbers.filter(n => n % 2 == 1);
}

/* Do not modify code below this line */

const oddNumbers = removeEvens([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
console.log(oddNumbers);
```