# When using `0` in a conditional why does the `0` render in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have no idea why, but I was getting a load of `0`'s being rendered on the page. Finally I narrowed it down to a zero/`0` that I wasn't forcing to be a boolean. React will not render any other digit other than `0`

https://codesandbox.io/s/pyk11w5y5j

Why does `0` render but `10` for example, does not render?

```
function App() {
  const weirdOh = -0;
  const testParam = true;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {testParam && weirdOh && <h1>Will Show</h1>}
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Fix**

```
{testParam && !!weirdOh && <h1>Will SHow</h1>}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642809/understanding-javascript-truthy-and-falsy

Answer (score 3):

Numbers are perfectly valid values in react, and `0` is just that, a number.

Make sure to convert it to a boolean to avoid this, since `false` doesn't render anything:

```
{testParam && !!weirdOh && <h1>Will Show</h1>}
```

or

```
{testParam && weirdOh !== 0 && <h1>Will Show</h1>}
```

If you set `weirdOh` to a non-zero number, then it won't be falsy, and your `<h1>` will be returned from the expression and be rendered.

---

This is not related to react, but simply how `&&` in JS works:

- `(1 && 'test') === 'test'` because after a truthy value, you go to the next one in the chain
- `(0 && 'test') === 0` because as soon as you hit a falsy value, that value is used

Comment: Why they, does `10` not render? This is also a digit?

Comment: Because that's truthy, so your `<h1>` will be returned from the expression.

Comment: Interesting, so because `0` is falsy it renders? I don't really understand why this renders just because it is falsey.

Comment: I understand that it is part of the expression, and being false means the `<h1>` doesn't render, but I can't bridge the cap to understanding why it renders.

Comment: Maybe you should be explaining how `testParam && weirdOh && <h1>Will Show</h1>` works to add more value to your answer

Comment: a `&&` chain stops as soon as something falsy is reached, and will return that element. if no values are falsy, the last one is returned. `1 && 'test' === 'test'` but ` && 'test' === 0`

Comment: Ah but of course... and any higher digit is truthy, hence why converting to a boolean it will cancel the chain and render nothing. Aka nothing to do with react