# If else if function with many or expressions wont cycle through all the or possibilities

Tags: javascript

I am displaying an image conditionally depending on what the value is. The value is a string. However it only returns the first image. It does not go through the entire function.

- I tried placing brackets around the values and it does work but only ever checks the first string.
- Tried using one equals sign, doesn't change anything.

```
  methods: {
    resultImage(value) {
      if (
        value === 'Less likely' ||
        'More likely light' ||
        'More likely blue' ||
        'More likely curly'
      ) {
        return this.low
      } else if (value === 'Average chance') {
        return this.medium
      } else if (
        value === 'Somewhat more likely' ||
        'Somewhat more likely brown' ||
        'Somewhat more likely curly'
      ) {
        return this.mediumHigh
      } else if (
        value === 'More likely' ||
        'More likely dark' ||
        'More likely brown' ||
        'More likely straight'
      ) {
        return this.high
      }
    }
  }
```

Expect the function to cycle to the end and return an image based on the value. Actual results is that it returns the first image.

Comment: What is the value of "value" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

currently, each string evaluates to `true` unless it is `null` or `undefined`. you're not comparing any of them to `value` except for the first one. you need to compare all of them, otherwise, the first if block will pass every time.

you're missing `value ===` on each expression:

```
 methods: {
    resultImage(value) {
      if (
        value === 'Less likely' ||
        value === 'More likely light' ||
        value === 'More likely blue' ||
        value === 'More likely curly'
      ) {
        return this.low
      } else if (value === 'Average chance') {
        return this.medium
      } else if (
        value === 'Somewhat more likely' ||
        value === 'Somewhat more likely brown' ||
        value === 'Somewhat more likely curly'
      ) {
        return this.mediumHigh
      } else if (
        value === 'More likely' ||
        value === 'More likely dark' ||
        value === 'More likely brown' ||
        value === 'More likely straight'
      ) {
        return this.high
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Explaining why `if (value === 'something' || 'something else')` won't give the expected result (and will always be evaluated as true) would make this a perfect answer

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you're not checking the value but rather the expressions.

```
if (
value === 'Less likely' ||
'More likely light' ||
'More likely blue' ||
'More likely curly'
)
```

will *always* result in true, because the expression 'More likely light' and the other strings are truthy values.
I think this will do what you want to achieve:

```
  if (
    value === 'Less likely' ||
    value === 'More likely light' ||
    value === 'More likely blue' ||
    value === 'More likely curly'
  )
```

I recommend this post: [Understanding JavaScript Truthy and Falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642809/understanding-javascript-truthy-and-falsy)

Answer (score 1):

try something like this instead:

```
function resultImage(value) {
    switch(value) {
        case 'Less likely':
        case 'Less likely':
        case 'More likely curly':
            return this.low
        case 'Average chance':
            return this.medium
        case 'Somewhat more likely':
        case 'Somewhat more likely brown':
        case 'Somewhat more likely curly':
            return this.mediumHigh
        case 'More likely':
        case 'More likely dark':
        case 'More likely brown':
        case 'More likely straight':
            return this.high
        default:
            return null
    }
}
```

You can also add a default case to return always a value.

Comment: Much nicer syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer to use an other pattern (tell don't ask)
Here is an exemple :

```
const cases = {
  'Less likely': 'low',
  'More likely light': 'low',
  ...
  'Average chance': 'medium',
  ...
  'Somewhat more likely brown': 'mediumHight',
  ...
};

methods: {
    resultImage(value) {
      return this[cases[value]];
    }
  }
```

I like to use this pattern to avoid multiple if - else if - else statements.

You can define a default value to enforce this pattern, like :

```
const cases = {
  ...
  default: 'low' // for exemple
}

methods: {
  resultImage(value) {
    const caseValue = cases[value] || cases['default'];
    return this[caseValue];
  }
}
```