# how to Log valid value to console in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to test an id value is nothing then I am logging in the console as "There is something in that" like that.
so how I can log if something entered in id.

This Code If Nothing Entered:

```
if(comItem == undefined){
    console.log('There Is Something in that value') 
} else {
    console.log('There is Nothing in that value')
}
```

I am Not Getting How to Do.

```
let comItem = 150;

if(comItem != undefined){
    console.log('There Is Something in that value') 
} else {
    console.log('There is Nothing in that value')
}
```

Comment: What's your problem? Your second code should log "*There is something in that value*". What doesn't work? Also, it's easier to use just `console.log ('comItem = ', comItem)`

Comment: if id is nothing i am successfully logging as



i am try to test an id value is nothing then i am logging in console as "Some Value" like that.. so how i can log if something entered in id..

This Code If Nothing Entered:
let comItem;

if(comItem != undefined){
    console.log('Some value') 
} else {
    console.log('No Value')
}

Comment: What is *nothing*? `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `0`, an empty string, or anything else?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want to test if `comItem` is a non-empty, non-whitespace string.

JavaScript has a very loose definition of the `==` operator - and it helps not to use `undefined` or `null` as operands unless you really know what you're doing.

I recommend reading these articles and QAs:

- [Understanding JavaScript Truthy and Falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642809/understanding-javascript-truthy-and-falsy)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy
- https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Anyway - the good news is that using just `if( comItem ) { ...` will work because it will evaluate to `true` if `comItem` is not `null`, and not an empty-string `""`, but you need a separate check for `undefined` (using `typeof`) if `var comItem` or `let comItem` (or `const comItem`) isn't guaranteed to be defined, like so:

```
if( typeof comItem == 'undefined' ) {
    console.log( );
}
else {
    if( comItem ) {
        console.log('There Is Something in that value') 
    }
    else {
        // `comItem` is either `undefined`, `null`, or an empty string
        console.log('There is Nothing in that value')
    }
}
```

If you want to test for a non-whitespace string you'll need a regex, like so:

```
if( comItem ) {
    if( /^\s+$/.test( comItem ) ) { // Test if the string contains only whitespace
        console.log('Whitespace string');
    }
    else {
        console.log('There Is definitely Something in that value');
    }
}
else {
    console.log('There is Nothing in that value');
}
```

Note that you cannot rely on only `if( /\S/.test( comItem ) ) { ...` because it evaluates to `true` for `null`.

So the total code is:

```
if( typeof comItem == 'undefined' ) {
    console.log( );
}
else {
    if( comItem ) {
        if( /^\s*$/.test( comItem ) ) {
            console.log( 'Is whitespace' );
        }
        else {
            console.log( 'Has a text value.' );
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log( 'Is null or empty' )
    }
}
```