# Defining: "this.isStartDateSet" vs. "!this.isStartDateSet"

Tags: javascript

This is a variable declared in my code.

```
var startDateSet = $(this.parentEl).find('input[name=daterangepicker_start]').val();
```

I understand that '!' is essentially the same as 'not' but I do not understand what it means when used in this context

```
if (!this.isStartDateSet) {
    var
    var
    var
    ............

}
```

does this just mean "if this start date is not set?"

Comment: Thanny, thats not a default Javascript Method, if you could include the variable isStartDateSet, or is it the same as isStartDateCal

Comment: @TaylorS I copied the wrong variable. It's fixed now.

Comment: The "logical NOT" operator will return `false` if the expression is _truthy_ which is very different than just checking if it's "not set"

Comment: @Bobtroopo and Nick --> thank you. this is helping me understand.

Comment: ! operator is used to finding whether the mentioned variable is null or having some object.

Comment: Are you using `this` or `var`? The two are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would mean:

> If isStartDateSet is falsy

Here is the list of `falsy` values:

1. `false`
2. `0`
3. `0n`
4. `""`, `''`, ``
5. `null`
6. `undefined`
7. `NaN`

More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35642837/7919626

Answer (score 0):

> var startDateSet = $(this.parentEl).find('input[name=daterangepicker_start]').val();

This is checking if you have set a Starting or Beginning Date-Time on your input.

(like if you have put a start value into the input, or if it has no value at the moment)

Then, the function:

```js
if (!this.isStartDateSet) {
    var
    var
    var
    ............

}
```

Is checking if there is NOT a starting date set, and is executing code inside of the conditional If statement.