# javascript filtering falsey values; Array.prototype.filter problems

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
//removes falsey values from the array
function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.filter(ele => ele);
}
console.log(bouncer([0, "ate", "", false, 9]));
```

I'm not understanding why the condition of just "ele" works here. I'm just returning the parameter, yet it won't return any falsey arguments through the function, so it works...? Why? Similarly I don't understand why I can't write that line as:
 *return arr.filter(ele => ele===true)*
My condition being: if an element of the array is true...return it, but this doesn't work and I don't understand why that is. I understand the code if I was trying to do a filter like (ele => ele>5)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove empty elements from an array in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281264/remove-empty-elements-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: "", undefined, 0 all are falsy value. user strict === to match false

Does this answer your question? [Understanding JavaScript Truthy and Falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642809/understanding-javascript-truthy-and-falsy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning just "ele" will evaluate as true everything that is NOT false i.e. not `0` or `""` or `false`. You get the same as `ele=>ele` if you do `ele=>ele!=false`

If you use `===true` then none of them is equal to true (type and value have to match `true`)

If you use `==true` then you still don't get anything because none of them evaluate to true (here the value `1` would pass the test)

Comment: Why do none of them equate to true? All values are truthy unless falsey. true means truthy right? So not falsey....i.e. if ele!=false means if ele ==true. I'm not understanding still.

Comment: In Javascript if a value is not true it doesn't mean it's false :) I advise you to read more on it on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: for a simple demonstration try: 'a'==true and 'a'==false. They both evaluate to false

Comment: If you are just trying to filter out everything that would evaluate to false, just use "ele" like you did, or "ele!=false"

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify condition on false

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  return arr.filter(ele => ele?true:false);
}
console.log(bouncer([0, "ate", "", false, 9]));
```

Comment: that code isn't correct. it doesn't filter falsey values out.

Comment: @kite, he has specified the condition `===false`(boolean) value only, and hence filter out false boolean value.

Comment: This is the output of the code as written:[0,"ate","",9] it's only removing the false value. I need all falsey values removed i.e. 0 and "". The answer should yield ["ate",9]

Answer (score 0):

It works because, you are using arrow function. So in your case `filter(ele => ele)` represents that you are only returning truthy values.

Now this won't `(ele => ele>5)` beacause your array contains other values apart from integer.

For better clarity you can read arrow function expressions from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) are values which are considered as falsy value in javascript.