# why there is no condition in the if statement when we use if(err) for mongoose query?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I know this might be a noob questions, but when I handle error for mongodb, why don't we put a condition like this in inside the if statement?

For example

```
query.findOne(function (err, kitten) {
    if (err === true) {
        console.log(err);
    } else if (!err) {
        console.log("success");
    }
}
```

How is `if(err)` equivalent to `if(err===true)`?

Comment: what is err here?

Comment: `if(err)` is not necessarily equivalent to `if(err===true)` - You need to check that in the console

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding JavaScript Truthy and Falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642809/understanding-javascript-truthy-and-falsy)

Comment: I am using the mongoose query for example query.findOne(function (err, kitten) {

Comment: because if (true) is the same as saying if (err===true) when err is true. As err === true also evaluates to true. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **err** is a boolean variable, and is set to *True*, then you do not need to write `if(err===True)` because it is the same as writing `if(True)` (because **err** is true).
In contrast, if you want to check if the condition is False, then you write `if(!err)`. If **err** is True, then !err= !True = False

Comment: This does answer my question, but I have something that I want to dig in. What if err is not an boolean value, for example when I use the mongoose query. I am not sure what kind of variable is the err, but I don't think its simply just a boolean variable since when I console log it, it shows more. And for this case, how would I understand this?

Comment: What does it show you, when you print it on console?