# Using -1 as a return value?

Tags: javascript

What does it mean when -1 is used as a return value as seen in the first if statement below?

```
MyLinkedList.prototype.get = function(i) {
    if (i < 0 || i >= this.length) return -1;
    if (i + 1 === this.length) return this.tail.prev.val;
    let curr = this.head.next;
    while (i--) curr = curr.next;
    return curr.val;
};
```

Comment: `-1 == false` will never be true, nor will `-1 == NaN`, nor will `-1 == undefined`. At best, this code checks if the JavaScript interpreter is following standards. That, or it's just completely meaningless.

Comment: "when -1 is used as a return value"...this code never does that. It's unclear how your question relates to the code.

Comment: In most cases if you want to signal using an int instead of a bool to say that there are outlying cases, -1 can be an acceptable value. For example, if I return a 1, then I'm implying that the expected condition was true, if I use a 0, it was false. However, in a case where there was an unexpected behavior, I might choose to use -1 to signal that a simple true/false dichotomy wasn't enough to describe that there was an issue.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642809/understanding-javascript-truthy-and-falsy

Comment: @Carson not a very good system. You can still just use booleans + `null` to signal the same.

Comment: You could, but not a very good system is some what arbitrary. It's a pretty common setup in academic coding environments.

Comment: OP seems to have [completely changed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63891346/revisions) the question and code sample a moment ago. Unclear if they posted the wrong thing or just thought better of the question. Any explanation please?

Comment: This question no longer appears to have *anything* to do with the original one.

Comment: Anyway in this case it seems the -1 is intended to indicate a validation error - specifically (if you read the `if` code) that the input value was outside the allowed range.

Comment: @Carson thanks that helps me better understand how -1 is used.

Comment: @ADyson yes I added new code because the first code was unclear to people.

Comment: @user12170797 well, more than that really, it seems to be completely unrelated to this code, which makes a lot more sense. That's why it seemed a bizarre change, but it has improved the question a lot.

Comment: @ADyson thanks, yeah i will be more direct next time I ask a question. the original code was my attempt at testing the bool value of -1, but guess it didn't make much sense.

Comment: No it didn't really to be honest. Especially because you asked why it returned -1, when it didn't do that at all! That was quite confusing. Anyway the new question is much better, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The numeric literal `-1` is technically considered [`Truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

Most functions that send `-1` as a return value are these that work with index values or other counting related problems dealing algorithms (example: [`String.prototype.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search))

Answer (score 2):

In this case it seems the `-1` is intended to indicate a validation error - specifically (if you read the `if` code) that the input value was outside the allowed range.

This should hopefully indicate to the caller that the value being returned is not a value from a real list item - although of course it's not entirely impossible that `-1` could be the value of one of the items in the list. Arguably it would be better to throw an error of some kind, or return `null`.