# Search for a JavaScript method to exclude elements

Tags: javascript

I found this `startsWith` method to select and filter 'keys' and then do something with the dataset in JavaScript,but now I look for a method which is the opposite of

```
str.startsWith(searchString[, position])
```

For example, I only want to display datasets which don't have a key which starts with 'article'.

```
const data = Object.entries(y)
  .filter(([key, value]) => (key.startsWith(!"article")))
  .map(([key, value]) => {}
```

the "!" Sign didn't work here. Does JavaScript offers a better nethode?

Comment: `!key.startsWith("article")`

Comment: `key.startsWith(!"article")` is same as doing `key.startsWith("false")`

Comment: `!` is a logical operator, which evaluate your value and return a `boolean`

[For more info: truthy-falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642809/understanding-javascript-truthy-and-falsy#:~:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20a%20truthy%20value,of%20falsy%20values%20in%20JavaScript%3A&text=undefined,-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't make sense:

```
!"article"
```

You don't want to negate the value of the *string*, you want to negate the value retuned by `.startsWith()`.  Semantically you want "not starts with" ("doesn't start with"):

```
!key.startsWith("article")
```