# How to check survival of Javascript object by operator "&&"?

Tags: javascript

My friend told me that this code "is used to check the survival of Javascript object":

Example:  I have 2 objects and each one has 2 property called 'a' and 'b'

```
var obj1 = {a:0,b:0}
var obj2 = {a:3,b:4}
```

With the obj1 with the value of all property is 0 and 'obj2' have child property's value is an integer and I make the 'obj1' to be the first operator of the  checking expression  then I have got result is "failed".

```
if((obj1.a && obj1.b)&& obj2){
    document.write("success")
}else{
   document.write("failed")
}
```

But otherwise if I make obj1 is the second operator then I have got result is "success" like this:

```
if((obj2.a && obj2.b)&& obj1){
    document.write("success")
}else{
document.write("failed")
}
```

Can anyone explain to me why?

```js
var obj1 = {a:0,b:0}
var obj2 = {a:3,b:4}


if((obj1.a && obj1.b)&& obj2){
   document.write("success")
}else{
  document.write("failed")
}

document.write("<br><br>")

if((obj2.a && obj2.b)&& obj1){
    document.write("success")
}else{
    document.write("failed")
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "survival"?

Answer (score 4):

> Can anyone explain to me why ?

You're observing [the *truthy and falsy* nature of JavaScript's type-system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642809/understanding-javascript-truthy-and-falsy).

The `if` expression in this:

```
var obj1 = { a: 0, b: 0 };
var obj2 = { a: 3, b: 4 };

if( ( obj1.a && obj1.b ) && obj2 ) {
```

is:

```
( obj1.a && obj1.b ) && obj2
```

...is effectively this:

```
( 0 && 0 ) && aNonNullObject

==

( false && false ) && true

==

( false ) && true

==

false
```

Whereas the other example:

```
if( ( obj2.a && obj2.b ) && obj1 ) {
```

...is:

```
( 3 && 4 ) && aNonNullObject

==

( true && true ) && true

==

( true ) && true

==

true
```

---

- This is because `0`, `null`, `undefined`, and empty-strings `""` are *falsy*.
- Whereas non-zero numbers, non-`null` objects, and non-empty-strings are *truthy*.

---

Also, [don't use `document.write`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

---

> "is used to check the survival of Javascript object"

"Survival" is not a term used in JavaScript - or programming in general, so I'd wager that your friend is not an expert at JavaScript programming - I assume you got into the habit of using `document.write` from them too, so I'll advise you to not be uncritical in response to anything they say.

("Object lifetime" and "lifespan" are terms that are used in programming, but they are unrelated to the question you're asking).

Comment: Very well explained.

Answer (score -1):

use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```js
var obj1 = { a: 0, b: 0 };
var obj2 = { a: 3, b: 4 };

if (obj1.hasOwnProperty('a') && obj1.hasOwnProperty('b') && obj2) {
  document.write("success"); // success
} else {
  document.write("failed");
}
```