# How can I check this function for truthy or return an empty array if falsy?

Tags: javascript, falsy, truthy

I am looking at this assignment, and my question is about the part in bold at the end:

> ```
> // Do not edit the code below.
> var myGroceryList = ['chips', 'pizza', 'hotpockets', 'MtnDew', 'corndogs'];
> // Do not edit the code above.
> ```
>
> Here we're going to write a function that mimics going shopping and checking things off of our grocery list and adding new items to our list.
>
> Write a function called removeItem that is given two arguments, the first is `myGroceryList`, and the second is an item to remove from `myGroceryList`.
> If the second argument (or the item to add or remove) matches an item in `myGroceryList`, remove that item from the your grocery list and return the new, updated grocery list.
>
> Once you do that, write another function called `addItem` that is given two arguments, the first is `myGroceryList` and the second is an item to add to your grocery list.
> In `addItem` add the item you passed in to `myGroceryList` then return the new, updated grocery list.
>
> **In both removeItem and addItem check to see if the 'myGroceryList' and 'item' arguments are truthy.
> If they are not, return an empty array.**
>
> Here are some examples of calling your functions and what should be returned:
>
> ```
> removeItem(myGroceryList, 'chips') --> ['pizza', 'hotpockets', 'MtnDew', 'corndogs'];
> addItem(myGroceryList, 'Jerky') --> ['pizza', 'hotpockets', 'MtnDew', 'corndogs', 'Jerky'];
> removeItem(myGroceryList) --> [];
> addItem() --> [];
> ```

Here is my code:

```
removeItem=(myGroceryList,item)=>{
   return myGroceryList.filter((thing)=>{
      return thing != item
   })
}

addItem=(myGroceryList, item)=>{
   myGroceryList.push(item);
   return myGroceryList;
}
```

How can I get the final step of this to work?

Comment: u can use if to check for truthy. if (! myGoceryList or  ! thing) return [ ];

Comment: You should clearly separate what is part of the assignment, and what is your work.

Comment: @Trincot, I updated this to say where my code starts. I honestly wasn't sure if filter of pop was better to use for the removeItem function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add an `if` that verifies the truthiness of both arguments:

```
removeItem=(myGroceryList,item)=>{
   if (!myGroceryList || !item) return [];
   return myGroceryList.filter((thing)=>{
      return thing != item
   })
}
```

### Not mutating the argument

As you are asked to return the new list, you did well to use `filter` and not mutate the original list. But you should better apply the same principle to `addItem`, which also is supposed to return the new list, and so it is better not to mutate the list that was given:

```
addItem=(myGroceryList, item)=>{
   if (!myGroceryList || !item) return [];
   return myGroceryList.concat(item); // don't use push, but concat
}
```

### Or... mutating the argument?

However, the example code that is given at the end of the assignment, *does not use the return value* of the function (except the console reporting it), and from the second call we can see that "chips" has actually been removed from the list that was *given* to the first call of `removeItem`.

So that means you have to make your functions having [side-effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)).

In that case you should not use `filter` or `concat`, but change the first function to use `splice`:

```
removeItem=(myGroceryList,item)=>{
   if (!myGroceryList || !item) return [];
   let i = myGroceryList.indexOf(item);
   if (i >= 0) myGroceryList.splice(i, 1); // mutate the list
   return myGroceryList;
}
```

...and you would use your version with `push` for `addItem`:

```
addItem=(myGroceryList, item)=>{
   if (!myGroceryList || !item) return [];
   myGroceryList.push(item); // mutate...
   return myGroceryList;
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, and makes a lot more sense now. Thanks for the help and the guidance on the addItem adjustement.

Comment: Upon reading the end of the assignment, with the test-code, I have had to add a section to my answer...

Comment: @ trincot  This works both ways for the purposes of the practice questions I am working through, but in real life if I were to make a simple website that allowed you to add and remove items, which do you think would be the smarter choice?  
.

Comment: There are different schools of thought (Look at *functional programming*). My preference is that functions that mutate the data structure that is given as argument, should not return the result -- as that suggests to the caller that it is a *new* data structure. So either such a function should return nothing, and just mutate the argument, or it should not mutate and return the new data structure. That is my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the insight on this topic, I will for sure look into this more to help get an idea of how I would like to handle these things!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of checking if truthy, you can check if falsy and return an empty array right away.

```js
   addItem=(myGroceryList, item) => {
      if(!myGroceryList) { return [] }
      myGroceryList.push(item);
      return myGroceryList;
   }
```

Comment: `if` statements boil their parameters down to either true or false - it doesn't really matter at that point whether or not it is a boolean. In fact, you are doing this here (it's overkill though). This is called truthy/falsy values. To see the list of falsy/truthy values go here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35642809/understanding-javascript-truthy-and-falsy (note: it really only shows you the falsy values, but using logic you can tell that the truthy values are everything that *isn't* falsy)