# DataTables render (multiple data in one column) does not show in Interface

Tags: jquery, sql, datatables

I am following this guide in order to add multiple data in my DataTables (js plugin) column:

https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/58795/add-multiple-value-in-column

**Here is the specific column in question:**

```
{ data: 'shift_name', name: 'shift_name', width: '15%', 
    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta )
    {
        return row.shift_name ? row.shift_name : 'N/A';
    },
    createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
        return $(td).css({
            'font-weight': "700"
        });
    }
},
```

**The Output:**

[image: 1]

Now I am trying to add another data underneath `shift_name` so here is what I tried first:

```
return row.shift_name ? row.shift_name : 'N/A' + '<br>hello';
```

The code above does not show the "hello" in each row

I also Tried adding a + at the start:

```
return + row.shift_name ? row.shift_name : 'N/A' + '<br>hello';
```

but for some reason my `shift_name` data does not get read this way:

[image: 2]

What is the correct way in adding multiple data in a row in my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the JavaScript [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) `? :`.

Your logic basically means *"if `row.shift_name` has a value, then display that value (and nothing else!) - but otherwise display `N/A` plus some additional text"*.

So, your logic means you only display that additional text if `row.shift_name` does not contain any value.

You can use parentheses to fix this:

```js
return (row.shift_name ? row.shift_name : 'N/A') + '<br>hello';
```

Now, the conditional `? :` operator is evaluated first - and then the extra text is appended to whatever the result of that operator is.

---

See also [Understanding JavaScript Truthy and Falsy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35642809/12567365) for a more precise description of how the condition is evaluated in your conditional operator.

Comment: quick and clear answer, thanks so much