# Need clarification understanding _.some()

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

It may be that I'm just very groggy this morning, but I'm having trouble understanding why this returns as `true`:

```
_.some([null, 0, 'yes', false]); // true
```

I know that `_.some()` returns true if at least one of the elements passes the predicate test as true. But from my understanding, if no predicate is provided, `_.identity()` is used. But console.log-ing each of those elements individually with `_.identity()` didn't return `true` for any of them. So why does it return true?

Comment: `'yes'` is truthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a predicate, `some` uses `identity`, which uses the value itself, and `'yes'` is truthy.

A quick dive through [the annotated source](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) (paying special attention to `cb` and the handling of missing predicates there) leaves you with, essentially, a coercion to boolean when they do:

```
if (predicate(obj[currentKey], currentKey, obj)) return true;
```

No predicate means you're working with the original value there, so `if ('yes')`, which is true.

You're not seeing `true` in the console for any of those values because `_.identity` will return the value itself (so `'yes'`) rather than coercing it to a boolean. If you were to do `!!'yes'` (coercion and double-not), you will see `true`.

Answer (score 2):

`'yes'` is truthy:

```
_.some([null])  // false
_.some([0])     // false
_.some(['yes']) // true
_.some([false]) // false
```

From [the Truth, equality in javascript link](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/):

The construct *if ( Expression )* Statement will coerce the result of evaluating the Expression to a boolean using the abstract method `ToBoolean` for which the ES5 spec defines the following algorithm:

`string`: The result is false if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero); otherwise the result is true.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't need to return the literal value `true`, it only needs to return a truthy value (although you always *should* return only booleans).

The [non-empty string `'yes'` is truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19839952/1048572) (you can test by `Boolean('yes')` or `!!'yes'`).