# Why does the following javascript code return true? Shouldn't it throw an error?

Tags: javascript, function, error-handling, syntax-error

Today, I had a typo that was hard to catch because it wasn't throwing an error as I would have expected...

After some quick testing the code below always returns true, and obviously, in this case returns 'first'. Why does this happen? And why doesn't it produce an error?

Here is a simple example of the code:

```
function func(num) {
  return num = 5 ? 'first' : 'second';
}

console.log(func(1)); // log 'first'
```

My linter caught it, but I was in a JSBin initially and didn't notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`num = 5 ? 'first' : 'second'` expression is evaluated as followed:

1. `5 ? 'first' : 'second'` expression is evaluated first (since the conditional operator has higher precedence than an assignment operator) and returns the value `'first'` since `5` is "truthy".
2. `num = 'first'` expression assigns the `'first'` string to the `num` variable and returns the `'first'` since the assignment operator `=` returns the right operand.

Useful links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence
- [All falsey values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19839952/251311)
- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-assignment-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation

Comment: How the hell are you so fast? Thanks for that @zerkms

Comment: @JordanHendrix I'm a cat - cats are quick :3

Comment: I get the second part, the 5 is truthy, the first part was more the issue, thanks again

Comment: @JordanHendrix yep, check the 1d and 1h items from the second link, it explains how the `=` operator returns the value.

Comment: That's almost but not quite right.  num is not assigned 5.  It is assigned `'first'`.  It is actually evaluated as `5 ? 'first' : 'second'` which evaluates to `'first'`.  That is then assigned to num.

Comment: @JordanHendrix—ECMAScript follows a precise language specification. Weird is doing an assignment in a return statement, but I guess you know that now. ;-) Very similar to doing `if (x = y)`, which sometimes people actually want, not `if (x == y)`.