# (!n%2) is the same as (!n%2 == 0)?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand this code from [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html#p_2qBy/XBHVa):

```
function unless(test, then) {
  if (!test) then();
}
function repeat(times, body) {
  for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) body(i);
}

repeat(3, function(n) {
  unless(n % 2, function() {
    console.log(n, "is even");
  });
});
// → 0 is even
// → 2 is even
```

I get that it says, run the following code 3 times testing with 0,1,2:

```
if (!n%2) function(n) {
  console.log(n, "is even");
});
```

What I don't get is how we get true/false from `(!n%2)`?

Is `(!n%2)` the same as `(!n%2 == 0)`?

Comment: as far as I know javascript evaluates an expression to true as long as it does not evaluate to `null` nor `undefined`. In other words, in javascript anything with a *valid/known* value evaluates to true.

Comment: @Veverke - ...or an empty string, or `0`.

Comment: Be as explicit as possible with your conditionals.

These "tricks" are language dependent, and nobody has enough time to memorize how every different language handles them.

so even if (!n%2) does what you want. Don't use it.

Comment: @JustinNiessner: an empty string and 0 - does not evaluate neither to null nor undefined, so it is covered in that definition.

Comment: truthy/falsey - See [All falsey values in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Although be careful: `!` has higher precedence than `%`. So `!n%2` is equivalent to `(!n)%2` not `!(n%2)`.

Comment: @Veverke - Wrong. Empty strings and `0` are both falsey in JavaScript. Using your definition, they should evaluate to `true`.

Comment: You've got a problem with [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). You probably meant to ask whether `!(n%2)` was equivalent to `!((n%2)==0)` (*No*) or maybe `(n%2) == 0` (*Yes*)

Comment: @JustinNiessner: you are right, thanks for that. May I ask what is the reasoning behind this behaivor ? I could find one in the definition I posed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test code you wrote is not equivalent to the sample code from the article.

In the sample code, `n % 2` is evaluated first, and the result is passed into the `unless` function.  There, you are performing a Logical Not operation against the result.

If `n` is even, `n % 2` will pass `0` to `unless`.  A Boolean comparison of `0` returns `false`, and the `!` negates the result (logical not), so `!0 == true`. this, in turn, causes the `then` function to fire.

If `n` is odd, the opposite occurs.  Some value other than `0` is passed, which evaluates to `false`, causing `then` to not fire.

In contrast, your attempt to reproduce the sample code without using Higher-Order functions won't work the same way.  `!n % 2` will perform the Logical Not on `n` first, then try to modulo the result.  `!(n % 2)` is a better representation of the sample code.

Comment: I see what you mean, I couldn't understand the flow in the code in the first place. I should first think in my mind what the result of `n % 2` is first and then apply the `!` on that result. This made it a lot easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

[Logical NOT `!`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT) has [higher precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table) than [modulo operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder).

Thus, `(!n%2)` is equivalent to `(!n) % 2` which will always return 0 a falsy value except when `n = 0`.

Whereas `(!n%2 == 0)` will return `true`(*again except 0*).

They both are not equal, in fact they are opposite of each other(falsy vs truthy value).

You need `!(n % 2)`.

Or simply to check if number is even

```
n % 2 === 0
```

Comment: It doesn't always return `0`. Try with `n=0`

Answer (score 0):

`!Boolean(n%2)` should work as a way to determine whether one is even or odd.

Remember that Boolean does not follow BIDMAS.

It does `!n` first where `n` is treated as a Boolean so that the numerical value of `0` is treated as `false` and any other numerical value is treated as `true`. The exclamation mark inverts the logic state of `n`.

Now the `%2` converts the Boolean back to an integer where `true` is `1` and `0` is `false`. `!n = 0` returns `0` and `!n = 1` returns `1`.

Using `!n%2` in an if statement converts it back to a Boolean (`1 = true`, `0 = false`).

Thus if `n = 0` then the if statements proceeds because it returned true. If `n != 0` (`!=` meaning not equal) then if statement is skipped because it returned false.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. As stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) the "!" operator has highest precedence than "%" so the expression will return true if n is 0 and false if n is different from 0.

More in detail, suppose n is 2. the execution of the expression is:

```
(!n)%2
(!2)%2
0%2
0
```

so it is false, now for n=0

```
(!0)%2
1%2
1
```

so it is true. It is the opposite behavior of (!n%2 == 0) that returns true if n is different from 0 and false otherwise since == has less precendence and the comparison with 0 is executed at the end of the calculation above. You can easily convince yourself by using this simple javascript with different values of n:

```
    n = 1;
    if(!n%2)
    {
        document.getElementById("par1").innerHTML="true";
    } 
    if(!n%2 == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("par2").innerHTML="true";
    }
```