# Need clarification using 0 with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I am reading source codes written in a game. Some lines are written as follows:

```
0 ? player.y > global.screenHeight/2 : global.screenHeight/2 - player.y
```

Assume that `player` is a sprite with position and `global` is just an import from other files which contains some properties. What does the above code do? I thought the ternary operator will be something like this:

```
c ? a : b
```

where `a` and `b` are of the same type and `c` is the condition.

But the game demo runs smoothly so the above code should be fine. I just don’t get the meaning of the code.

The code is extracted from here:
https://github.com/huytd/agar.io-clone/blob/master/src/client/js/app.js

Comment: `0` would make the condition false. But I don't see the point of it, that line does nothing useful.

Comment: It looks like someone flipped the condition and the then expression.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek but running 0?1:2 in developer console will log 2, so is it that the *global.screenHeight/2 - player.y* will be executed?

Comment: @user2181397 Yes, looks like the `0` was just a placeholder that they forgot about.

Comment: Falsy in JS : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19839953/5395773

Answer (score 1):

In the above ternary statement `0` is the condition.

Because Javascript treats `0` as [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), the statement is evaluated as if written as:

```
false ? player.y > global.screenHeight/2 : global.screenHeight/2 - player.y
```

Therefore, `global.screenHeight/2 - player.y` will be returned.

It is possible the author put the ternary there to act as an on/off switch. By replacing the `0` with a `1`, the ternary statement would return `player.y > global.screenHeight/2` instead.

Comment: So this `player.y > global.screenHeight/2 ` is useless ? Why would it be written like this?

Comment: Maybe the author wanted to keep a switch for testing etc, so that the author could replace the `0` with a `1` and have the other statement be returned instead.

Comment: It should also be added that in `c ? a : b`, `a` and `b` *do not* need to be the same type since JavaScript is [loosely typed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Dynamic_typing). In fact in this case it will either return a number (or `NaN`) if the condition is `false` or a boolean if the condition is `true` because `player.y > global.screenHeight/2` will evaluate to a boolean. I think this is actually a bug in that code, the author probably accidentally swapped the condition and the "if true" expression.

Comment: Using a ternary as an on/off switch is kind of an interesting idea. I normally would just write it as two lines and comment one out because: a) unnecessarily evaluating the condition could cause a slight performance hit and more importantly: b) it makes the intent of the code more clear to anyone reading it. That said, point a might be moot because most modern JS engines would probably optimize away the unreachable code path since the condition is a primitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
c ? a : b
```

`a` and `b` can evaluate to values of any type, and `c` will evaluate to `true` or `false`.

`0` will evaluate to `false`, "b" will run: `global.screenHeight/2 - player.y`
This will happen regardless of anything else - the first expression will never run.

If I had to guess why that's in there, I'd say it may be a placeholder for a planned feature or improvement (however I obviously can't know for sure).

Comment: `0` will not *likely* be `false`, it will **always** be `false` since `0` is a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value and will always be coerced to `false`.

Comment: Yeah, only put the likely in there since I haven't used JS in a while and didn't want to assume the behavior (even though 0 should evaluate to false for most uses)

Answer (score 0):

```
0 ? player.y > global.screenHeight/2 : global.screenHeight/2 - player.y
```

Here 0 is false , So the `global.screenHeight/2 - player.y`  will be always executed