# indexOf but for objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexof

I want to look through an object and assign each of it's existent properties to a variable.

There are 4 possible properties. Some of the objects have all 4. Some might only have two.

How can I check if a particular property exists? Is there an equivalent of indexOf() for arrays but for objects instead?

Comment: It is really tough to imagine your code from just plain text. Care to reveal the relevant source code here? This is so that we can better help you.

Comment: Have you tried `hasOwnProperty` or converting the object to array with `Object.keys`?

Comment: if the properties can't be false (eg they are all sub-objects), then duck typing is readable and fast : `if(obj.key1); alert(obj.key1.name);`

Comment: `false` or [_falsey_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19839953/1848578), including `0` and other common values

Comment: @qxz: yeah, that's what i meant, good call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in properties set directly on the object (not accessible via the prototype chain) then [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) will provide a boolean value, `true`, if an object has the specified property.

For example: `testObject.hasOwnProperty('propertyToCheckFor')` would return `true` if `testObject.propertyToCheckFor` exists, otherwise it would be `false`.

See the following code for a more expanded example:

```js
var obj1 = {
  a: 1
};
var obj2 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
var obj3 = {
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};
var obj4 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
};


// For dispaly purposes
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify({
  obj1: {
    hasA: obj1.hasOwnProperty('a'),
    hasB: obj1.hasOwnProperty('b'),
    hasC: obj1.hasOwnProperty('c')
  },
  obj2: {
    hasA: obj2.hasOwnProperty('a'),
    hasB: obj2.hasOwnProperty('b'),
    hasC: obj2.hasOwnProperty('c')
  },
  obj3: {
    hasA: obj3.hasOwnProperty('a'),
    hasB: obj3.hasOwnProperty('b'),
    hasC: obj3.hasOwnProperty('c')
  },
  obj4: {
    hasA: obj4.hasOwnProperty('a'),
    hasB: obj4.hasOwnProperty('b'),
    hasC: obj4.hasOwnProperty('c')
  }
}, null, 2) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: `{hasOwnProperty: Boolean}` ?

Comment: @dandavis What? If someone does that then they deserve the 7th ring of hell they find themselves in.

Comment: i thought so too, until i found it in the wild on an excel spreadsheet about real estate that was converted to JSON. it wasn't a function, so it just threw, but it made me super anal about checking object membership...

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) keyword:

`"key" in object`

which returns `true` or `false`, depending if the object, or anything in its prototype chain, has that property.

You can also use [`object.hasOwnProperty("key")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), which will only be `true` if the object has `key` as a property of itself, not its prototype. Example:

```
var object = {};
"toString" in object; // true
object.hasOwnProperty("toString"); // false
```

Note (as per @dandavis's comment) that if `object` has a custom property called `hasOwnProperty`, this gets thwarted; to work around this, use `hasOwnProperty.call(object, "key")`. Example:

```
var a = {hasOwnProperty: Boolean};
a.hasOwnProperty('name'); // true
hasOwnProperty.call(a, 'name'); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  baz: 3
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  window[key] = obj[key]
})

console.log(foo, bar, baz)
```

Or in ES2015

```js
const obj = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  baz: 3
}

function assignPrivateVars() {
  let {foo, bar, baz} = obj;
  console.log(foo, bar, baz);
}

assignPrivateVars();
```

Comment: Object.keys+forEach works well, but is much slower than a filtered for-in for large objects...

Comment: don't use large objects ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use destructuring assignment. If value is not defined, variable will be set to `undefined`. You can also check if variable is defined after destructuring then `delete` variable by reference.

```
var data = {a:1, b:2, c:3};

var {a, b, c, d} = data; // `d`: `undefined`
```

Comment: Note that this an an ES6 feature, and doesn't have wide support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Browser_compatibility

Comment: that's really neat and clean, but i don't think it's exactly what OP needs because it's just as complicated (if not more so) to check for a lexical as a member.