# Show different content if 'ko with' is not displayed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using the following knockout code to display properties from an object.
Using the `with` i can check if the properties in this object exist.

```
<!-- ko with: Bunk1 -->
<div data-bind="css: Color">
    <div class="row no-margin">
        <div>
            <div data-bind="text: Name"></div>
            <div data-bind="text: FirstName"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

This is the model:

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Bunk1 = ko.observable();
    self.Bunk2 = ko.observable();
    ...

    ...

    // 'val' is loaded with $.ajax 
    // this code might not be executed and  Bunk1 can fail to initialize.
    var model = new BunkModel();
        model.initModel(val);
        self.Bunk1(model);

    ...
}

function BunkModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Color = ko.observable();
    self.Name= ko.observable();
    self.FirstName= ko.observable();

    self.initModel = function (values) {
        self.Color(self.mapColor(values.color));
        self.Name(values.name);
        self.FirstName(values.firstName);
    }
}
```

What i would like to do is to display an alternative `div` if there is no data, something like an `else` to the `ko with`. How can i bind the object properties but display alternative data if they don't exist.

Comment: What about a simple `ko if: Bunk1() === undefined` or `ko if: Bunk1() === null` after the `ko with` block?

Comment: didn't know about `undefined`. `ko if Bunk1() === undefined` seems to work. `null` doesn't work because it seems to be initialized after `self.Bunk1 = ko.observable();`

Comment: OK, I'll convert that to an answer. Asked first because it seemed rather obvious, but perhaps not to a Knockout beginner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a new observable without passing a value, its value will be `undefined`. This means you can simply add a conditional block below the existing `with` block:

```
<!-- ko if: Bunk1() === undefined -->
content here
<!-- /ko -->
```

Note that you need to use parentheses when doing a comparison like this, `Bunk1 === undefined` would check if the observable itself is undefined instead of its underlying value.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Stijn answer.

You can use "[ifnot](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/ifnot-binding.html)" binding:

```
<!-- ko ifnot: Bunk1 -->
content here
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: This'll work too, indeed, since `undefined` is [falsey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript).