# JavaScript: typeof fooVariable !== 'undefined' vs fooVariable

Tags: javascript

Instead of doing ...

```
if (typeof some !== 'undefined' && some.thing.variable === 'someValue')
```

... is it acceptable to just do the following?

```
if (some && some.thing.variable === 'someValue')
```

Comment: Just use `someVariable === 'someValue'`.

Comment: Do you care about other falsey values? If so - no, otherwise - yes.

Comment: Actually, yeah Tushar is right - you don't really need to check for undefined first if you want exact match anyway - by definition the value can't be `undefined` if it's `"someValue"`

Comment: Best practice: be explicit whenever possible (the first one is more explicit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All falsey values in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Your update doesn't change anything. Unless you do `typeof some !== "undefined" && some.variable == "someValue"` in which case it would make more sense and then the second form `some && some.variable == "someValue"` is perfectly acceptable and idiomatic.

Comment: So you are saying that it makes sense to have `if(some)` instead of `if(typeof some)`. But when does it make sense to have `typeof`?

Comment: When you want to check for `undefined`. Or if it's another type, like number or string, but in this context, it's just `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks.  Does a variable default to null or undefined?

Comment: @Grateful well if you just do `var a;` it will be `undefined`. It follows logically, as the value is...not surprisingly, _not_ defined. You could set the value explicitly to `undefined`, as well but, in general, `undefined` means "I have not assigned a value yet, so it's empty" and `null` means "I have set a value myself and that value is empty", so when assigning "non-values" yourself, you should prefer `null`. Also be aware that `if (a)` will NOT pass for `0` or `""` yet, they may be valid values, e.g., `totalAmount = 0` http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Answer (score -2):

### Yes, this is acceptable in a private function. Just make sure you have declared the variable `some` to avoid a `ReferenceError`.

Rationale: Since there are a few downvotes I think I need to give some context to why I think this is acceptable. I mention "private function" because in a private function the assumption is that we know which objects have which properties. So - regardless of style - the second write-up is an acceptable alternative to the original code snippet only if `some` is indeed the object as advertised.

The function in question would need to have the variable declared and should not be accessible from outside. Some start these variables with an underscore:

```
// Declare variable
var _some;
```

Comment: if `obj` is undefined, you will still get an error. If you have a deeper nesting, your code becomes unreadable. The best would be : `if (obj && obj.p) {}`. But anyway, it's just code styles that can only create debates, SO is not for that kind of answer.

Comment: Oops! True that. Fixed. For readability you can wrap it in a function. But my point is that checking for `undefined` is pointless if you are not sure the property exist, as it will error either way.