# Why `("" || "word") == true` returns false?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators, boolean-logic

I'm currently learning JavaScript and I am really confused about this.

Can anyone explain how this is possible :

```
"" || "word" // -> "word"

("word") && true // -> true

("" || "word") == true // -> false
```

I have tried to search online but can't find the proper words to describe my problem.

Comment: so what is your problem?

Comment: [Binary Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#Binary_logical_operators)

Comment: See [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Comment: Some more reading stuff about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript

Comment: So do you expect "word" to equal true?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND

Comment: If you want to get the correct result you need to convert your string to boolean like this : !!("" || "word") == true  -> true

Comment: `if ("" || "word") console.log("it returns true!")`

Comment: `!!("" || "word") == true  // -> true`

Comment: `"word" != true` ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Question 1

> ```
> "" || "word"  // -> "word"
> ```

As described in the [documentation on `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

> **Logical OR (`||`)**
>   `expr1 || expr2`
>   Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to `true`; otherwise, returns `expr2`.

In this case, the first expression `""` [is falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), so the second term is the outcome of the expression. If the first expression would have been truthy, the second term would not have been evaluated, and the first one would be returned.

#### 2. Question 2

> ```
> ("word") && true // -> true
> ```

As described in the [documentation on `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

> **Logical AND (`&&`)**
>   `expr1 && expr2`
>   Returns `expr1` if it can be converted to `false`; otherwise, returns `expr2`.

Here the first expression is truthy and so JavaScript returns the last one. If the first one would have been falsy, the return value would have been the first term.

#### 3. Question 3

> ```
> ("" || "word") == true // -> false
> ```

As per the first expression outcome, this is equivalent to:

> ```
> "word" == true // -> false
> ```

With the `==` operator the coercion happens differently. [`true` is coerced into a string value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators), i.e. `"1"`, which evidently is not the same as `"word"`. If the first term would have been `"1"` or just 1, it would have yielded `true`:

```
"1" == true // -> true
1 == true // -> true
```

#### Practical use

If you have a condition like the last one, just write it without the comparison:

```
if ("" || "word") {
    console.log('it is truthy!');
}
```

Or if you really need `true` as the result, convert it explicitly to boolean [with `!!`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript):

```
result = !!("" || "word");
```

Answer (score 2):

There's more to truth in JavaScript than `true` or `false`.

There are also truthy values and falsey values, and everything is either truthy or falsey.

`false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and `NaN` are falsey.
Everything else is truthy.

The logical operators operate on truthy and falsey things;

```
a && b
```

is

- `a`, if `a` is falsey
- otherwise, it is `b`

and

```
a || b
```

is

- `a`, if `a` is truthy
- otherwise, it is `b`

(If you're familiar with Lisp or Python, this is perfectly natural. If you're not, you're probably thinking "WAT?!".)

Hence,

```
"" || "word"  -> "word"
```

because `""` is falsey,

```
"word" && true  -> true
```

because `"word"` is truthy, and

```
("" || "word") == true  -> false
```

because `"" || "word"` is `"word"`, and `"word"` is not the same object as `true`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you understand the first two boolean, and have some confusion in the last one.

Your question is, if first 2 are `true`, why the last one is not `true`.

There is a concept of `thruthy` and `falsey` values in Javascript. A `thruthy` value may or may not be a `Boolean`, but still satisfies the `if` conditions.

For example, in case of string, an empty string is a `falsey` value, and a string with even a single character is `thruthy`.

A `truthy` value is **equivalent** to `true`, but not **equals** to `true`. Same for `falsey`.

In the last case, `("" || "word") == true`, the left part equals `word`, and the operator used, `==` checks if the left value equals right value. So `word` is not equal to `true`, hence returns `false`.

```
("" || "word") == true // lets simplify
"word" == true // false, "word" is not equal to true
```

But if you use `word` in an `if` condition, it will satisfy the condition since it's a `thruthy` value.

```
if ("word") { /* condition will be satisfied */ }
if ("") { /* condition will NOT be satisfied */ }
```

To check whether a value is `truthy` or not, use `!!` before the value.

```
// String
!!"word" // true
!!""     // false
// Number
!!5      // true
!!0      // false
// Boolean
!!true   // true
!!false  // false
```