# Wrong value in case of 0 using elvis operator in angular2

Tags: angular

let suppose I am accessing and showing data in html like this

```
{{whole_data?.age_range ? whole_data?.age_range : '-'}}
```

Now problem here is, if in case `whole_data?.age_range` is evaluated to `0` or `null` it will show `-` always, except expression value is non zero or not null,

My question is

1. why so (is zero is treated as false in this case) ?
2. what is the alternate for the same ?

PS:- I don't want to use condition especially for checking value is zero or not, because this syntax I am using 1000 of times in my code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

You can make your template expression shorter, but it will have the same outcome:

```
{{whole_data?.age_range || '-'}}
```

There is no other way. `0` is always evaluated to false. You should use a pipe to prevent duplicate code:

```
@Pipe({
    name: "dashNumber"
})
export class DashNumber implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: number): number {
        value = parseFloat(value);
        return isNaN(value) ? '-' : value;
    }

}
```

usage:

```
{{whole_data?.age_range | dashNumber}}
```

Comment: thanks for the tip @PierreDuc , but this will not solve my problem at all, +1 for `{{whole_data?.age_range || '-'}}`

Comment: @PardeepJain then what is your problem :)