# what is the condition of "if"?why it continue when it's false?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I set condition that  a number greater than surrounding,but it go a false.

```
for (var i = 0; i + 1 < n; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1] || arr[i + 1] > arr[i + 2]) {
        count++;
        index1 = i + 1;
    }
}
```

arr=[1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8],n=8.

You can see count plus when arr[i+1] smaller than arr[i+2].

[image: this is the picture of problem]

Comment: please add the missing variables, like `arr` and `n` and what you expect.

Comment: What does `arr` contain?

Comment: what are you expecting?

Comment: What you are looking for is `&&` instead of `||` maybe. `true` or `false` returns `true` (as in your condition).

Comment: arr is in the picture.

Comment: You should use `&&` instead of `||` as @sha

Comment: according to the picture arr[i] < arr[i + 1]  is interpreted to arr[0] < arr[1] i.e 1< 2 is true and by OR condition the if expression is true isn't it ?

Comment: You are using OR condition so it will continue because one statement is true

Answer (score 0):

You should use AND condition instead of OR to check value is greater than left and right.

Refer below code:

```js
var arr=[1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8];
var n=8;
var count = 0;
var pos = [];
for (var i = 0; i + 1 < n; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1] && arr[i + 1] > arr[i + 2]) {
        count++;
        index1 = i + 1;
        pos.push(index1);
    }
}
console.log("positions: "+pos);
console.log("count: "+count);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the condition of ||(OR) since

```
true || false will result in true
```

Also, &&(AND) will result in

```
true && false will reult in false
```

So modify your function using "&&" instead of "||"

```
var arr=[1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8];
var n=8;
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i + 1 < n; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1] && arr[i + 1] > arr[i + 2]) {
        count++;
        index1 = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators for further understanding

Answer (score -1):

When i is reaching 6, you test array[i+2] with i+2=8, so the index i+2 is out of bound (the array contains 8 elements, with index starting from 0 to 7).
In js, getting a value out of array returns undefined, which is evaluated as a falsy value (evaluated as false).

You can get an explanation about falsy values here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19839953/5520709