# Is this a good way to check for undefined values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently transitioning from promises to async await. And its been easier to reason about code. I just have a question on if using way to check for undefined is good. The code is being used in nodejs and checking against a database. The code goes something like this.

Edit: I am aware that I'm supposed to catch for errors. I just got lazy here.

```
// This is a hypothetical function
async function retrieveUser(userID){
  let user = await databasefetchfuction(userID);
  if(user) return user;
  return;
}

controller.getUser = async function(req,res){
 let user = await retrieveUser(req.params.userID);
 if(!user){ // Is this ok?
   return res.status(404).json();
 } 
 return res.status(200).json({ user });
}
```

I was if doing this is fine or if I should explicitly check for undefined using `user === undefined`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for [a code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Depends really. Are any of `false`, `""`, `0`... valid return values or should they be errors too?

Comment: Your current form will return properly for the following values: `null`,
`undefined`,
`NaN`,
`empty string ("")`,
`0`,
`false`

Comment: Isn't the real question will this check if my method returned a value? What do these methods do exactly? The result will depend on that.

Comment: @Quentin I'm not really asking for a code review. The purpose of the code was to show an example. This code is fictitious. I just want to confirm behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(!user)` is fine as long as you are willing to accept that it will be true for all the other "falsey" things in JS.

See this: [All falsey values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript)

Comment: This explanation will suffice. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Using !var is perfectly fine in the case of a database return. There is no way that a user was found but !var returns true.

Answer (score 0):

The `undefined` value in JavaScript is treated as a falsy value, so yes - you are doing it in a proper way. If you want to check other field in user object, you should check both `user` and `user.property`.