# reactjs, loop through an item and if condition on markup

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a reactjs component. I have 3 items, that I am looping through - but I only wish to show a button, under the first item. I am getting a syntax error.

```
<div className='row grid__row--offset--50'>
        <div className='small-55 medium-58 large-58 small-centered columns background--white--small border__transparent--top'>
          {
            lang.howTiles[0].items.map(function (item, index) {
              return (
                <div key={index}>
                  {index}
                  <div className='small-60 columns grid__row--offset--30 show-for-small-only'>&nbsp;</div>
                  <div className='small-45 medium-20 small-centered medium-uncentered columns'>
                    <div className='row'>
                      <div className='small-60 medium-45 small-centered columns'>
                        <div className='relative-container'>
                          <img className='centered' src={HowImage1} style={{maxWidth: '50%', marginLeft: '25%'}} />

                          <h3 className='text--bold text--center'><font><font>Project</font></font></h3>
                          <p className='text--center text--font-size-14'><font><font>Write out your project and show it to a hand-picked group of experts</font></font></p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    {
                      if(index==0){
                        <div className='grid__row--offset--40 row'>
                          <div className='small-40 columns small-centered'>
                            <a className='text--white text--center text--font-size-14 button medium radius secondary' href={lang.howTiles[0].button.url}><font><font>{lang.howTiles[0].button.title}</font></font></a>
                            <a href='http://localhost/slack'><img alt='Add to Slack' height='40' width='139' src='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png' srcSet='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png 1x, https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack@2x.png 2x' /></a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      }
                    }
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            })
          }

          <div className='medium-60 columns grid__row--offset--30'>&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div className='row grid__row--offset--80'>&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Unexpected token bug -- I tried wrapping the fragment of html in an return ()

Answer (score 2):

We can't directly use `if-else/switch` statement inside `JSX`, use either `ternary operator` or call a function from JSX and use `if-else/switch` inside that.

Use this:

```
{
    index == 0 ?
        <div className='grid__row--offset--40 row'>
          <div className='small-40 columns small-centered'>
            <a className='text--white text--center text--font-size-14 button medium radius secondary' href={lang.howTiles[0].button.url}><font><font>{lang.howTiles[0].button.title}</font></font></a>
            <a href='http://localhost/slack'><img alt='Add to Slack' height='40' width='139' src='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png' srcSet='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png 1x, https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack@2x.png 2x' /></a>
          </div>
        </div>
    : null
}
```

**Update:**

Another possible solution is call a function from render method and use the if condition inside that, like this:

```
{
    this._checkCondition()
}

_checkCondition(index){
    if(index == 0){
        return (
            <div className='grid__row--offset--40 row'>
              <div className='small-40 columns small-centered'>
                <a className='text--white text--center text--font-size-14 button medium radius secondary' href={lang.howTiles[0].button.url}><font><font>{lang.howTiles[0].button.title}</font></font></a>
                <a href='http://localhost/slack'><img alt='Add to Slack' height='40' width='139' src='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png' srcSet='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png 1x, https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack@2x.png 2x' /></a>
              </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

For more details why we can't use if-else in JSX check the [DOC](http://reactjs.cn/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html).

Comment: that worked.. but why did this take - and not the above sample -- is there a version - where what I had done - would work -- wrapping it in {}, return?

Comment: check the updated answer, provided a link to doc why we can't we if-else inside jsx?

Comment: {(() => {
    if(index == 0){
        <div className='grid__row--offset--40 row'>
          <div className='small-40 columns small-centered'>
            <a className='text--white text--center text--font-size-14 button medium radius secondary' href={lang.howTiles[0].button.url}><font><font>{lang.howTiles[0].button.title}</font></font></a>
            <a href='http://localhost/slack'><img alt='Add to Slack' height='40' width='139' src='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png' srcSet='' /></a>
          </div>
        </div>
    }
)()}

Comment: because you are creating a function by `{(() =>` and using if condition inside that, it will work, i mentioned that in my answer you can call a function and use the if condition inside that.

Comment: -- what about the other answer -- he says it would work with just wrapping the markup with ()

Comment: that is also correct, since you just want to render that part when index will be zero, and don't want to render anything when condition fails that's why. So it will be easy to use ! of index.

Comment: think it should be ===

Comment: you can use === also, here index will always be number that's why, there will be no problem with ==.

Comment: 99:36  error  '?' should be placed at the beginning of the line  operator-linebreak

Comment: ^ code is breaking -- ? should be placed at the beginning?

Comment: the first part should work use that in same way, like this: `{index == 0 ? ....}`

Comment: it should - it was -- but its busting

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try other approach. If `index==false` all between () will be rendered. Remember - javascript [has dynamic typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript)

```
    {!index &&
    (<div className='grid__row--offset--40 row'>
      <div className='small-40 columns small-centered'>
        <a className='text--white text--center text--font-size-14 button medium radius secondary' href={lang.howTiles[0].button.url}><font><font>{lang.howTiles[0].button.title}</font></font></a>
        <a href='http://localhost/slack'><img alt='Add to Slack' height='40' width='139' src='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png' srcSet='https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png 1x, https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack@2x.png 2x' /></a>
      </div>
    </div>)}
```

Comment: ^ so this looks similar to what I was trying to do before -- where the markup is wrapped up ?

Comment: Yes. Try this too. Only if index is 'falsy' the thing between () will be rendered

Comment: well index would be 0 -- as it hits the first element?

Comment: it's not clear, what do you mean? If index is 0 - it will be treated as false in heare

Comment: well the index is going to be an int -- as it loops through an array of data -- 0,1,2 -- so instead of !index -- should be index ===0

Comment: I updated the answer. Please find out more about javascript dynamic typing.