# Why does an assignment in an if statement equate to true?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, equality, equals-operator

Let me start off by saying I understand the difference between `=`, `==`, and 
 `===`. The first is used to assign the right-hand value to the left-hand variable, the second is used to compare the equivalency of the two values, and the third is used not just for equivalency but type comparison as well (ie `true === 1` would return `false`).

So I know that *almost* any time you see `if (... = ...)`, there's a pretty good chance the author meant to use `==`.

That said, I don't entirely understand what's happening with these scripts:

```js
var a = 5;

if (a = 6)
 console.log("doop");
```

```js
if (true == 2)
 console.log('doop');
```

According to this [Javascript type equivalency table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35MpY.png), `true` is equivalent to `1` but not `0` or `-1`. Therefore it makes sense to me that that second script does **not** output anything (at least, it isn't in my Chrome v58.0.3029.110).

So why does the first script output to the console but the second doesn't? What is being evaluated by the first script's `if` statement?

I dug into my C# knowledge to help me understand, but in C# you cannot compile `if (a = 5) Console.WriteLine("doop");` so I had to explicitly cast it to a bool by doing `if (Convert.ToBoolean(a = 5))` but then that makes sense it would evaluate to true because according to MSDN's documentation, `Convert.ToBool` returns true if the value supplied is anything other than `0`. So this didn't help me very much, because in JS only `1` and `true` are equal.

Comment: That "equivalency table" is wrong. *Any* non-zero number is `true` when tested as a boolean, as is any non-empty string.

Comment: Because the value of an assignment expression is the value that was assigned.

Comment: @CBroe: Slightly more formally it's the new value of the "lvalue" being assigned to.

Comment: The `=` operator returns the assigned value. Meaning the value of the expression `a = 6` is `6`. That's used in things like `a = b = 6` (`a = (b = 6)`)…

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript

Comment: @Pointy So then why does my second script not write to the console?

Comment: Because `true` is not equal to `2`

Comment: @Pointy Thank you; I understood the explanation that time. If you want to post that as the answer, I'll accept it. With your explanation I now understand Quentin's answer, but as his answer stands it doesn't help me understand so I don't want to accept his.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between making an abstract equality comparison with `==` and performing a simple type cast to boolean from a number value. In a `==` comparison between a boolean and a number, the boolean value is converted to 0 or 1 *before the comparison*. Thus in

```
if (true == 2)
```

the value `true` is first converted to `1` and then compared to `2`.

In a type cast situation like

```
if (x = 2)
```

the number is converted to boolean such that any non-zero value is true. That is, the value `2` is assigned to `x` and the value of the overall expression is `2`. That is then tested as boolean as part of the evaluation of the `if` statement, and so is converted as `true`, since `2` is not `0`.

The various values that evaluate to boolean `false` are `0`, `NaN`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course `false`. *Any* other value is `true` when tested as a boolean (for example in an `if` expression).

Answer (score 1):

> Why does an assignment in an if statement equate to true?

It doesn't. An assignment is evaluated as whatever value is assigned.

This expression is a true value:

```
a = true
```

But this expression is a false value:

```
b = false
```

That's true whether or not you put it in an `if` statement or not.

Comment: [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](https://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) doesn't compare truthiness when you have a boolean on the LHS.