# Mongo Find is not working

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This is my user schema

```
 var UserSchema = new Schema({
        Pcard: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Pcard'  }]
})
```

These are id's saved in user Pcard array

```
  "user": { // id 59560bc83e1fdc2cb8e73236
     "Pcard": [
                "595b43d16e4b7305e5b40845",
                "595b459a6e4b7305e5b40848",
                "595f48f58117c85e041f1e1c",
            ],
}
```

This is my Pcard Scema

```
var PcardSchema = new Schema({
    Time : {
        type : Date,
        default: Date.now
    },

})
```

I want to find user having Id and which also contains some id in Pcard array

```
User.find({  _id: req.user._id,
                       Pcard:{$in : [req.params.PcardId] }
                    }, function (err, Userpresent) {
                         if (err) {
                                res.json(code.Parked);
                           }
                          if (Userpresent === null || Userpresent === undefined) {

                     res.json(code.notAllowed);
                         }else{

This else is execting everytime.



}                        
    }
                    });
```

when i querying with user which does not have a Pcardid in Pcard array it is still going in else condition ! 
for eg . i am querying with this id 59560bc83e1fdc2cb8e73236 and this not contain 5957bd177e996b56d08b991a in Pcard array but still it is going on else part of the user query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB find with id and id in array using $in operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007161/mongodb-find-with-id-and-id-in-array-using-in-operator)

Comment: not working either

Comment: You are saying it always finds a user ? even if the PcardId is not present in the Pcard array ?

Comment: @RohailNajam Yes ,  i want to find the user if both these conditions matches

Comment: It most likely won't matter, but you don't need to use `$in`, just use `{ _id : req.user._id, Pcard : req.params.PcardId }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are expecting only one user, use [findOne](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html).

Might be useful/cleaner for you to [return early](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement) instead of having a bunch if-else.

```
User.findOne({  
    _id: req.user._id,
    Pcard: { $in : [req.params.PcardId] }
}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
        return res.json(code.Parked);
    }
    // simplified: undefined and null are both falseys
    if (!user) {
        return res.json(code.notAllowed);
    }

    // user should be found at this point

});
```

Good read: [All falsey values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19839953/1022914)

Comment: Thanks , But it is not working with just using Find ?

Comment: If you use `find`, it should be `user[0]` that you should be working with. But remember `find` is more expensive than `findOne` as you are looking for many results opposed to just one.