# hasOwnProperty("foo") always returns true even if I assigned foo to undefined - why?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I want to set the property of object to something if condition is true, else do nothing.

And I tried to use `?` operator by

```
obj.prop = (...)?sth:null;
```

and

```
obj.prop = (...)?sth:undefined;
```

But it turns out that nether one of them can perform what I want.

Given the condition is false, when I called `obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)`, it always gives me true.

Is there a way to do it?

I know I can do it by using `if` syntax but I just want to know if I can do the same thing using `?` operator.

Comment: There is no `?` operator, except in some proposals and some Babel plug-ins.

Comment: the ternary operator is `? :`.  a `?` by itself is not an operator

Comment: I mean using the ? : syntax to write if statement

Comment: Modify the title to make it clearer

Comment: you mean the obj.prop is not getting set to null or any value OR it gives you any error? Have you checked your browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign a property like this:

```
var obj = {
    a : undefined // or any other value
};
```

this happens according to the ECMAScript spec:

> [11.1.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) Object Initialiser
>
> [...]
>
> The production PropertyNameAndValueList : PropertyAssignment is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let obj be the result of creating a new object as if by the expression new Object() where Object is the standard built-in constructor with that name.
> 2. Let propId be the result of evaluating PropertyAssignment.
> 3. Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of obj with arguments propId.name, propId.descriptor, and false.
> 4. Return obj.

When you assign a property like this:

```
obj.a = undefined;
```

this happens according to the ECMAScript spec:

> [8.12.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.5) [[Put]] ( P, V, Throw )
>
> [...]
>
> 6. Else, create a named data property named P on object O as follows
>      a. Let newDesc be the Property Descriptor
>          {[[Value]]: V, [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: true, [[Configurable]]: true}.
>       b. Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of O passing P, newDesc, and Throw as arguments.

In either case, since `undefined` and `null` are legimite values, this will just define the property with this value.

Finally, `hasOwnProperty()` will only check if a property descriptor was created, the value does not matter:

> [15.2.4.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.5) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty (V)
>
> [...]
>
> 3. Let desc be the result of calling the [[GetOwnProperty]] internal method of O passing P as the argument.
> 4. If desc is undefined, return false.
> 5. Return true.

But, according to the ECMAScript spec, both a property set to `undefined` and a not set property, will return `undefined` if you access them:

> [8.12.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.3) [[Get]] (P)
>
> [...]
>
> 2. If desc is undefined, return undefined.
> 3. If IsDataDescriptor(desc) is true, return desc.[[Value]].
> 4. Otherwise, IsAccessorDescriptor(desc) must be true so, let getter be desc.[[Get]].
> 5. If getter is undefined, return undefined.
> 6. Return the result calling the [[Call]] internal method of getter providing O as the this value and providing no arguments.

Proof:

```
var obj = {
  a : undefined
}

console.log(typeof obj.a); // undefined
console.log(typeof obj.b); // undefined
obj.hasOwnProperty('a') // true
obj.hasOwnProperty('b') // false
```

---

Only `delete` will remove the property.

```
var obj = {
  a : null,
  b : undefined
}

obj.hasOwnProperty('a') // true
obj.hasOwnProperty('b') // true

delete obj.a;
delete obj.b;

obj.hasOwnProperty('a') // false
obj.hasOwnProperty('b') // false
```

Reading the ECMAScript spec on `delete` is left to the reader.

Comment: I think Henry is trying to set it to some value , not trying to delete/remove the prop

Comment: @Sujith `[...]Given the condition is false, when I called obj.hasOwnProperty(prop), it always gives me true.[...]`. If the condition is `false` the OP assigns `null` or `undefined`, but that would not change `obj.hasOwnProperty('prop')` to `false` it will still stay `true`.

Comment: so by using ? : operator, prop is created no matter condition is true or false. Right?

Comment: @HenryHung yes it will always create a property. Because you will always assign the result of your `?:` expression to `obj.prop`.

Comment: @t.niese: updated your answer to reference the ECMAScript spec on the relevant cases. Obviously the inner workings of `[[Put]]` and `hasOwnProperty()` was unclear to the TO, so I though it would be nice to elaborate a bit more on that. I hope you like the edit, if you don't: just revert it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the result of your condition is falsy enough, something like this should work.
[All falsey values in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript)

```js
var obj = {

  a: true,
  b: false,

}

obj.prop1 = obj.a ? true : false;
obj.prop2 = obj.b ? true : false;

console.log(obj);
```